# what i am further to do..I got a Prime Numbers to be print ,non prime numbers are am not able to print

Tags: java

```
Input:20
Output:0 is not a Prime
       1 is not a prime
       2 is a prime 
       3 is a prime 
       4 is not a prime 
       5 is a prime
       20 is not a prime(upto number 20)
```

My Class

```
public class Prime{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int number=20;
        int p;
        for(int i=2;i<number;i++){
            p=0;
            for(int j=2;j<i;j++){
                if(i%j==0){
                    p=1;
                }
            }
            if(p==0){
                System.out.println(i+" "+"Is Prime");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above program I  printed the prime numbers,How to print both prime and non prime numbers in it?Thanks in advance! 
check it from 0 is not a Prime, 1 is not a prime, 2 is a prime, 3 is a prime, 4 is not a prime, 5 is a prime, 7 is a prime, 8 is not a prime ,continues upto n given

Comment: Hint. `if(p == 0){/*I am prime*/}else{/*I am not prime*/}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prime Number Generator Logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435289/prime-number-generator-logic)

Comment: There are zillions of pages out there on prime-number generator algorithms, some on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `else` block to the `if` statement that can print non-prime numbers.

```
if(p==0){
    System.out.println(i+" "+"Is Prime");
}
else {
    System.out.println(i+" "+"Is not Prime");
}
```

> Update:

Also modify your for loop statement like so:

```
System.out.println("0 is not Prime");
System.out.println("1 is not Prime");
for(int i=2;i<=number;i++){
```

This will iterate from 0 to 20.

Comment: Yup! but if i added these lines it gives the output from 2 to 19 only.I have to start with the 0 to 20.0 is not a prime 1 is not a prime. 2 is a prime.Likewise upto  20 is not a prime.

Comment: 0 and 1 is not a Prime .If am declaring the for loop as like for(int i=0;i<=number;i++).It returns the output 0 is a prime 1 is a prime.

Comment: By definition, 0 and 1 are not prime numbers and are generally not considered while calculation. You can choose to print them separately before starting your loop..

Answer (score 0):

Modify condition for not prime also check if value is 0 0r 1 then print number is not prime.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number=20;
    int p;
    if(number==0 || number ==1){
         System.out.println(number+" "+"is not a Prime");
    }
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
        p=0;
        
        for(int j=2;j<i;j++){
            if(i%j==0){
                p=1;
            }
        }
        if(i==0 || i ==1){
         p=1;
         }
        if(p==0){
            System.out.println(i+" "+"Is Prime");
        }else{
            System.out.println(i+" "+"is not a Prime");
        }
    }
}
```