# Check if number is decimal with swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can i check if a number is decimal or not using swift?

With Objective-C:

```
if (number == (int) number) {
  //decimal
}
else {
  //not decimal
}
```

Comment: What does "is decimal" mean? If you're asking is if it's an integer, I'm providing you an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you round the number down (which you can do by using the floor function), and then subtract it from the original number, you will get the difference between the two.

```
if (number - floor(number) > 0.000001) { // 0.000001 can be changed depending on the level of precision you need
    // decimal
}
```

Edit --

My original answer recommended calculating the difference between the number and its floored equivalent to see if there were any units after the decimal points. However, as later described, there may be a rounding error which causes the representation of a value in memory to be slightly different than what it's actually meant to be.

For example, 3.0 could be represented as 3.00000000000001, and therefore the `number - floor(number) > 0` would return true, even though it should've theoretically returned false as the offset would be 0.00000000000001.

**Therefore please use @jessy's answer below.**

Comment: I would recommend a small nonzero value instead of zero, e.g. 0.000001.

Comment: @Sulthan for what reason?

Comment: @max_ because with floating point math, you sometimes get values like 3.000000001 or 2.999999999999 instead of integers. The value you use instead of 0 depends on how close to an integer you want to count as an integer. Is .001 close enough? Is .000000001?

Comment: However, note that `floor` will break for negative numbers... `-1.0000000001` will get floored to `-2`.

Comment: I don't know if your > should be a <, or "is decimal" means something other than "is an integer". If not, let the compiler define the tolerance.

Answer (score 73):

```
extension FloatingPoint {
  var isInteger: Bool { rounded() == self }
}
```

(You'll also need to use the `return` keyword if you're not using Swift 5.1 or later.)

Comment: This should be the correct answer! Just stop messing around with 0.00000XX

Comment: This might not give the results you expect sometimes, due to floating-point imprecision. For example: `((0.1 + 0.2) * 10.0).isInteger` will be `false`. Comparing the rounded value against `self` with a tolerance will give you a more reliable result.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka What you're talking about is valid, and [addressed in SE-0259](https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0259-approximate-equality-for-floating-point/23627).  But `isAlmostEqual` is not the same thing as `is`—the latter should match up with `==`, and `(0.1 + 0.2) * 10 != 3`. `isAlmostInteger` would follow, if the proposal ever bore fruit.

Comment: @Jessy Mathematically, though, `(0.1 + 0.2) * 10` _does_ equal `3`; the reason it doesn't in computing is only due to imprecision in floating point math. In almost all practical cases, the mathematical result is what the user wants and the FP idiosyncracies are just an implementation detail. Most of the time, to match user expectations, it's better to figure out what degree of precision your use case requires and compare your floats accordingly.

Comment: To phrase it differently, I see this question as finding out if a `FloatingPoint` value represents what you get if you use [`init(some BinaryInteger)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/init(_:)-2f8bx). If you disagree, please add another answer that represents how to solve the problem for your use case.

Answer (score 8):

Swift:

```
if number.rounded(.up) == number.rounded(.down) {
    //number is integer
} else {
    //number is not integer
}
```

Packaged up nicely in an extension:

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    var isInteger: Bool { rounded(.up) == rounded(.down) }
}
```

Comment: Works well. I have to detect if the calculated number is having decimal points greater than 0.                                                                                                                 5 / 2 = 2.5. 6 / 2 = 3.0

Answer (score 3):

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    var isInteger: Bool {
        return truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0
    }
}
```

We can divide the number by 1 to get the same number and then examine its remainder. A number that has no remainder is a whole number (integer).

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

```swift
if yourNumber % 1 == 0 {
    // yourNumber Doesn’t Contain Decimal 
else{
    // yourNumber Contain Decimal 
}
```

**or**

```swift
if floor(yourNumber) == yourNumber {
    // yourNumber Doesn’t Contain Decimal
}else{
    // yourNumber Contain Decimal 
}
```

The **floor()** function in Swift returns the next largest integer that is less than or equal to a specified number

to understand more about floor [here](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-floor-function-in-swift)