# Swift: Check if datatype can be converted to Double

Tags: ios, swift

I want to check if the received data from a **MySQL-database** can be converted to **Double** and if that's possible I want to append it to an array.

From another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315723/check-if-string-is-a-valid-double-value-in-swift) i got the following code:

```
extension String {
    struct NumberFormatter {
        static let instance = NSNumberFormatter()
    }
    var doubleValue:Double? {
        return NumberFormatter.instance.numberFromString(self)?.doubleValue
    }
    var integerValue:Int? {
        return NumberFormatter.instance.numberFromString(self)?.integerValue
    }
}
```

Here's my concerned Code (which is in a **for-loop**):

```
if let value = datas[i].puls.doubleValue {
    pulsWerte.append(value)
    print(datas[i].puls)
}else {
    badIndex.append(i)
    continue
}
```

In case an entry of my database is **NULL**, my program should proceed in the **else**-branch. But if I test such a case I end up with a runtime-error and the following two messages:

```
-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1451238
```

&

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1451238'
```

Does anyone know my mistake?

### UPDATE

This is how my **datas**-array gets created:
For downloading and allocating the data I'm using **Objectiv-C**.
In my Data.h-file I create my **Data**-class.

```
@interface Data : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sozialversicherungsnummer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *messzeitpunkt;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *puls;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sauerstoffgehalt;

@end
```

And in my HomeModel.m I create a **NSMutableArray** named "_data". After my download is finished this array gets filled as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];

    // Create a new data object and set its props to JsonElement properties
    Data *newData = [[Data alloc] init];
    newData.sozialversicherungsnummer = jsonElement[@"Sozialversicherungsnummer"];
    newData.messzeitpunkt = jsonElement[@"Messzeitpunkt"];
    newData.puls = jsonElement[@"Puls"];
    newData.sauerstoffgehalt = jsonElement[@"Sauerstoffgehalt"];

    // Add this question to the locations array
    [_data addObject:newData];

}
```

When this step is completed I get this **"_data"-array** under the name of a parameter called **"items"** by a function called **"itemsDownloaded"**.
And now I call this function in my **Swift**-file and here I'm able to **typecast** the downloaded **"items" as "Data"** (my self created class).

```
func itemsDownloaded(items: [AnyObject]!) {
    let datas = items as! [Data]
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of `doubleValue:Double?` assumes that self is a `String`.

```
    var doubleValue:Double? {
        return NumberFormatter.instance.numberFromString(self)?.doubleValue
    }
```

The `datas[i].puls` is created by an Objective-C JSON Parser which produces in the case of `NULL` an instance of `NSNull` but you expect to set nil.

The easiest way is to check `jsonElement[@"Puls"]` for `NSNull` and then set `newData.puls` to `NULL`:

```
id puls = jsonElement[@"Puls"];
if puls == [NSNull null] {
  newData.puls = null;
} else {
  newData.puls = puls;
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your support! Unfortunately I have to tell you that your suggestion doesn't solve my problem. It seems that my code is still trying to reach the length method...I get the same errors...

Comment: Could you explain how the datas[i].puls structure ist created?

Comment: I extend my suggest solution. I forgot to check the type via the is operator. Please try again.

Comment: Ok, I will try again. I've extended my question with the informations you've wanted before.

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't work...maybe the warnings I get could help you:
- @ **as? String**-cast: Conditional cast from 'String!' to 'String' always succeeds
- @ **is String**-cast: Conditional cast from 'String!' to 'String' always succeeds & 'is' test is always true
- @ **is NSNull**-cast: Cast from 'String!' to unrelated type 'NSNull' always fails

Comment: Hehe okay... Now I understand. ;-) As I said it's important to know how the datas[i] structure is created. Do you have any insides?

Ah I see you update. Thx. I take a look.

Comment: Ok :-). What do you mean with "insides"?

Comment: Insides like you made in your edit question.

I updated my answer too. ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much! With your updated answer I was able to fix it! :-)

Answer (score 3):

First of all you can define the following protocol.

### DoubleConvertible

```
protocol DoubleConvertible {
    func toDouble() -> Double?
}
```

### Making String, Int and Double conform DoubleConvertible

Next, for each type that you want to be convertible to `Double` you need to make that type conform to `DoubleConvertible`.

Let's do it for `String`

```
extension String: DoubleConvertible {
    func toDouble() -> Double? {
        return Double(self)
    }
}
```

and `Int`

```
extension Int: DoubleConvertible {
    func toDouble() -> Double? {
        return Double(self)
    }
}
```

and ... well `Double`

```
extension Double: DoubleConvertible {
    func toDouble() -> Double? {
        return self
    }
}
```

### From [Any] to [Double]

Now given a list of values of several different types

```
let list: [Any?] = ["123", nil, "Hello", 456, true, 789.1]
```

We can easily convert it to a list of `Double`.

```
let listOfDouble = list
    .flatMap { $0 as? DoubleConvertible }
    .flatMap { $0.toDouble() }

listOfDouble // [123.0, 456.0, 789.1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal for solution! Unfortunately I have to say that this doesn't solve my problem. I still get the same errors in the line: .flatMap { $0 as? DoubleConvertible }

Comment: I mean the two messages on my output I mentioned in my question: "-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector..."

Comment: @S.Schweng: please this line before my block of code: `print(list)` and let me know what does appear in the log.

Comment: I tested your code with exactly the same **"list"**-array and I got the expected output: "[123.0, 456.0, 789.1]". But when I test my **datas**-array like this:
    let listOfDouble = datas
        .flatMap{$0.puls as? DoubleConvertible}
        .flatMap{$0.toDouble()}
    print("listOfDouble: \(listOfDouble)")
I end up with a runtime-error again...

Comment: And in my log those two messages appear again.

Comment: I need you to put this line `print(data)` **before** my code. I need to see what's inside your array. Please try and le me know what does appear in the log.

Comment: Ok, so this appears when I print the "datas"-array: [<Data: 0x792ded60>, <Data: 0x792dee10>, <Data: 0x792dee30>, <Data: 0x792dee50>, <Data: 0x792dee70>, <Data: 0x792deeb0>, <Data: 0x792deed0>, <Data: 0x792deef0>, <Data: 0x792def10>, <Data: 0x792dee90>, <Data: 0x792def70>, <Data: 0x792def90>, <Data: 0x792defb0>, <Data: 0x792defd0>, <Data: 0x792deff0>, <Data: 0x792df010>, <Data: 0x792df030>, <Data: 0x792df0c0>, <Data: 0x792df0e0>, <Data: 0x792df100>, <Data: 0x792df120>, <Data: 0x792df140>, <Data: 0x792df160>]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102375/discussion-between-appzyourlife-and-s-schweng).