# check string is int or double , with extension in swift 3

Tags: swift, string

I have string extension you can see under below but only returns true for **Int** , I want to return it true, for All , **Int** and **Double** values only.

```
extension String  {
    var isnumberordouble : Bool {
        get{
            return self.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix it ? Any idea ? ty.

Comment: Just check if the string can be *converted* to an Int or a Double. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/30315832/1187415.

Comment: What about `2.` ?

Comment: @NiravD what ? , I want to check only string if int or double must be return true if not , must be false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @MartinR said, check if the string can be converted to an `Int` or a `Double`:

```
extension String  {
    var isnumberordouble: Bool { return Int(self) != nil || Double(self) != nil }
}

print("1".isnumberordouble)      // true
print("1.2.3".isnumberordouble)  // false
print("1.2".isnumberordouble)    // true
```

---

@MartinR raises a good point in the comments.  Any value that converts to an `Int` would also convert to a `Double`, so just checking for conversion to `Double` is sufficient:

```
extension String  {
    var isnumberordouble: Bool { return Double(self) != nil }
}
```

---

**Handling leading and trailing whitespace**

The solution above works, but it isn't very forgiving if your `String` has leading or trailing whitespace.  To handle that use the `trimmingCharacters(in:)` method of `String` to remove the whitespace (requires *Foundation*):

```
import Foundation

extension String  {
    var isnumberordouble: Bool { return Double(self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)) != nil }
}

print("  12 ".isnumberordouble)     // true
```

Comment: Checking for Double might be sufficient... A string representing an integer should also be a valid double.