# How can you determine whether a double is an integer?

Tags: swift, integer, double

Is there anyway in Swift 3 to determine whether a double value has decimal places or not? In my program, I only want to perform a calculation to this double if it is an integer value. How can I check to see if there's non-zero numbers after the decimal point?

For example:

```
let double dx = 1.0 // This would return true
let double dy = 1.5 // This would return false
```

Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks,

Matthew

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/ / http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html

Comment: Do you mean "an integer" in the mathematical sense, or "exactly representable as an `Int`"? For example, `pow(2.0, 100.0)` is an exact integer, but too large for `Int`.

Comment: @MartinR I meant integer as in the mathematical sense. Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 2):

`Double` values will almost never be truly whole, they'll just be "close enough" according to some `wholenessThreshold`. You can set this to your needs, and use it like so:

```
let dx = 1.0
let dy = 1.5

extension Double {
    private static let wholenessThreshold = 0.01

    var isWhole: Bool {
        return abs(self - self.rounded()) < Double.wholenessThreshold
    }
}

print(dx.isWhole) // true
print(dy.isWhole) // false
```

Comment: Calling that property `isWhole` is misleading. `1.0/1024.0` is *not* a "whole number" or "integer". So what you are testing if the number is "close to an integer" with some precision. Or perhaps you mean: That number is the result of a computation which *would* be an integer if done with infinite precision. – In any case, the precision or "wholenessThreshold" strongly depends on the calculation and context, which means that defining the precision  as a  static constant makes no sense.

Comment: That's why I've havent made it public. What name would you suggest?

Comment: The `isWhole` property is internal, i.e. used throughout the entire app. I don't know a good name, but (in my opinion) the precision should be a *parameter* of such a function. – But anyway: It is still unclear (to me) what OP actually wants to achieve, there are different ways to interpret the question.

Comment: @MartinR I'm aware it's internal. I was considering making the `wholenessThreshold` a parameter, but it's largely arbitrary and would just lead to needless repetition. I kept it simple.

Answer (score 2):

```
extension Double {
    var isInt: Bool {
        let intValue = Int(self)
        return  Double(intValue) == self
    }
}
```

**Not working when value out of Int range.

Comment: `isInt(9999999999999999999.0)` => boom.

Comment: Another counter example: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58bcf67d8d0bc30581d03dd7

Comment: Also, this should be a computed variable in an extension on Double, rather than a free function

Comment: @Alexander: A counter-example for what? The final `sum` in your program is not an integer and `isInt` correctly reports that.

Comment: @MartinR It illustrates how one can easily come to a double value that's intended to be an integer, but isn't due to rounding rules. Any discussion of "wholeness" of floating point values is incomplete without a threshold that defines "wholeness"

Comment: @MartinR is show Double values will almost never be truly whole, see Alexander answer below

Answer (score 2):

If the floor value of double equal to that double then it considered as Int otherwise it is Double.

```
let dx: Double = 1.0
let dy: Double = 1.5
let isInteger = floor(dx) == dx // return true
let isInteger = floor(dy) == dy // return false
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work reliably due to floating point rounding errors.

Comment: @Alexander:  `floor(dx) == dx` returns true exactly if `dx` represents an integral number.

Comment: @MartinR Not when you're dealing with the realities of floating point math, but you know this.

Comment: @Alexander: That is a different problem. `1.0` is equal to an integer, the result of `0.3 + 0.6 + 0.1` is not.

Answer (score 2):

Originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59339620/8408162).

```
extension Double {
    var isInteger: Bool {
        return truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0
    }
}
```

We can divide the number by 1 to get the same number and then examine its remainder. A number that has no remainder is a whole number (integer).

Comment: `let d:Double = 0.9999999999999999999999    
print(d.isInteger) // true`