# Checking if a float can be an integer and returning it without the .00

Tags: swift

I am doing a quiz percentage although it currently returns as [Mark].00. If the number is a whole number like 86% or 100% I want to return just the whole number, but if the number is example 75.77 then return that.

I currently have this.

```
  func getScorePercentage() -> String {
    let result = (quizScore / Float(allQuestionsCount)) * 100

    if result as? Int {
       // return String(result)
    }

     return String(format: "%.2f", (quizScore / Float(allQuestionsCount)) * 100) + "%"
    }
```

Comment: :/ Maybe consider using a `NumberFormatter`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I dont need that, I need to get rid of the .00 if its a whole number

Comment: You are the one who is _putting_ the `".00"` there. If you don't want it, don't do that.

Comment: @matt What is it a float? I it to show as float

Comment: It's a _string_. It's text. You are in complete command of it. Just make it look the way you want. Also a good idea is to listen to advice you are given; asking a question implies that you don't know the answer, so you should not assume that an answer is wrong, because you have no ability to judge.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617928/how-can-you-determine-whether-a-double-is-an-integer

Answer (score 1):

Quick playground test...

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0

formatter.string(from: NSNumber(floatLiteral: 100.00))
formatter.string(from: NSNumber(floatLiteral: 75.77))
formatter.string(from: NSNumber(floatLiteral: 100.003))

String(format: "%.2f", 100.00)
String(format: "%.2f", 75.77)
String(format: "%.2f", 100.003)
```

Which outputs...

```
"100"
"75.77"
"100"

"100.00"
"75.77"
"100.00"
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved it myself with floor.

```
  func getScorePercentage() -> String {

        let result = (quizScore / Float(allQuestionsCount)) * 100

        let isInteger = floor(result) == result

        if isInteger {
            return "\(Int(result))%"
        }

         return String(format: "%.2f", (quizScore / Float(allQuestionsCount)) * 100) + "%"


    }
```