# How to check a string is a decimal or not in Swift

Tags: swift, string, decimal, swift5

I have tried code below.
My expectation is `isDecimal("56.0")` should return true.
And `isDecimal("56")` should return false,
also `isDecimal(".")` should return false
but the function is returning true always. Please anyone help in this issue.

```
func isDecimal(str : String) -> Bool {
    if let _ = Decimal(string: str) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

I have to verify there is always a integer after (dot). like 15.0 or 15.1. It should not be 15.a or 15. or 15.#

Comment: What exactly is your definition of a "decimal"?

Comment: A decimal is a number that consists of a whole and a fractional part. like 56.0 , 15.5

Comment: Why not simply `Decimal(string: str) != nil`?

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus for your reply but checkDecimal(str: "56") is returning true not false, as "56" is not having any fraction. Tried func checkDecimal(str : String) -> Bool {
        Decimal(string: str) != nil
    }

Comment: Your expectation is wrong: `Decimal(string: str)` will only fail if `str` is not a number at all. E.g. `isDecimal("fifty-six")` will fail. You need to do something like this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552648/check-if-number-is-decimal-with-swift

Comment: @sfgblackwarkrts suggested answer will fail when I will check for 56.0 as it is having decimal 0 after the number.  56.0 - floor(56.0) > 0 .

Comment: @adilRaza My point was that you are building on wrong expectation. The post I linked gives several ways to check for decimal. You can also (since your input is string) use a regex (this is what I would do actually). Or you can try to split the string by decimal character (locale specific) and see if you have 2 tokens. There are many ways. None of them includes converting to decimal though

Comment: I also have to verify there is always a single integer after (dot). like 15.0 or 15.1. It should not be 15.a or only 15. or 15.#