# Find the biggest prime of a number [Python]

Tags: python, primes, prime-factoring

```
def f(num):
    return num

number = f(13195)
list = [ x for x in range(number) if ((x!= 0 and x!=1) and number%x ==0)] #x (the multiplication factor) should not be 0 or 1
max = max(list)
for num in range(1,max) :
    if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,num)):
       if num in list:
           print num
```

Hello, this code is used to find the biggest prime of a number.
i have tried using f(13195) and i found the correct numbers, but I got an error of too many items in range, is there any other way of solving this?

But when I typed  600851475143,it says the range has too many items, however, does it mean I should not use range? Thanks in advance !

Comment: have you tried xrange?

Comment: @lejlot hi, i'm beginner. I will check it out now! :)

Comment: @lejlot I tried, however, the number is still too big, it shows another error.

Comment: What is the purpose of the for loop? Why not just do `print(list)`?

Comment: Also what is the purpose of the function `f`? You can change `number = f(13195)` to `number = 13195`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice There is no purpose for that line . sorry my bad , haven't been coding for ages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math
def f(num):
    return num

number = f(600851475143)
list = [ x for x in xrange(int(math.sqrt(number))) if ((x!= 0 and x!=1) and number%x ==0)] 
max = max(list)
for num in xrange(1,max) :
    if all(num%i!=0 for i in xrange(2,num)):
       if num in list: # if sth is true it runs...
           print num
```

I figured it out, we need to change the range up to square-root of the number, I changed the algorithm rather than trying to find some range bigger than xrange in python

Please find detail explanation here: If you are interested:) "second reply"
[Why do we check up to the square root of a prime number to determine if it is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-upto-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pri)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xrange(number)` instead.

However the loop will take a very long time for large numbers

Alternatively use Python3 where `range` behaves like `xrange`

Comment: it now says Python int too large to convert to C long, let me look into it.

Comment: It doesn't work, don't know how to fix it, can you help me ? Thanks!