# Prime number checker returns the same result each time

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm a beginner programmer learning Swift and made a basic prime number checker. No matter what it will only give one result, instead of changing based on wether or not the number is prime. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@IBAction func primeCheck(sender: AnyObject) {

var numberInt  = number.text.toInt()
var isPrime = true

    if number != nil {        
        if numberInt == 1 {      
            isPrime = false
        }

        if numberInt != 1 {         
            for var i = 2; i < numberInt; i++ {        
                if numberInt! % i == 0 {
                    isPrime = false
                } else {
                    isPrime = true
                }
            }
        }

    }

    if isPrime == true {
        result.text = "\(numberInt!) is a prime number!"
    } else {
        result.text = "\(numberInt!) is not a prime number!"
    }

}
```

Comment: if numberInt% i != 0 {

                    isPrime = false

                } else {

                    isPrime = true

                }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You have to break out of the loop after you find that the number is divisble by another number**. Also for prime check you only have to check the divisibility till the square root of the number.

You can also use optional binding to extract `numberInt` and check for nil. That's the swift way.

```
@IBAction func primeCheck(sender: AnyObject) {

    var isPrime = true
    if let numberInt  = number.text.toInt() {

        if numberInt == 1 {
            isPrime = false /
        }
        else // Add else because you dont have to execute code below if number is 1
        {
            if numberInt != 1 {
                for var i = 2; i * i <= numberInt; i++ { // Only check till squareroot
                    if numberInt % i == 0 {
                        isPrime = false
                        break // Break out of loop if number is divisible.

                    } // Don't need else condition because isPrime is initialised as true.
                }
            }
        }

       if isPrime {
          result.text = "\(numberInt) is a prime number!"
       } else {
          result.text = "\(numberInt) is not a prime number!"
       }
    }

}
```

Reason for square root check : [Why do we check up to the square root of a prime number to determine if it is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-upto-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pri)

You can refine the code further by refactoring the prime check into a separate function.

```
func isPrime(number:Int) -> Bool
{
    if number == 1 {
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        if number != 1 {
            for var i = 2; i * i <= numberInt; i++ {
                if numberInt % i == 0 {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}

@IBAction func primeCheck(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let numberInt  = number.text.toInt() {

        if isPrime(numberInt) {
            result.text = "\(numberInt) is a prime number!"
        } else {
            result.text = "\(numberInt) is not a prime number!"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: LOL, that updated code looks awfully familiar... I wonder where it came from? It's almost like mine but will take twice as long to run. lol. Oh well, not all the best answers are accepted.

Comment: oh yeah. even number skipping. i forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

I have another possible solution. At first I divide by two because it cannot be a prime number. Then you loop until the number is prime or the number divided by two is less than the divider.

```
@IBAction func primeCheck(sender: AnyObject) {

    var numberInt  = number.text.toInt()
    var isPrime = true
    var divider = 3

    if number < 2 || (number != 2 && number % 2 == 0) {
        isPrime = false
    }

    // you only have to check to half of the number
    while(isPrime == true && divider < number / 2){
        isPrime = number % divider != 0
        divider += 2
    }

    if isPrime == true {
        result.text = "\(numberInt!) is a prime number!"
    } else {
        result.text = "\(numberInt!) is not a prime number!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your logic comes in this section:

```
if numberInt! % i == 0 {
    isPrime = false
} else {
    isPrime = true
}
```

At the top of your function, you initialize `isPrime` to be true, so in your loop you only need to look for cases that prove the number is *not* prime. You don't ever need to set `isPrime = true` again, so just drop the else condition:

```
if numberInt! % i == 0 {
    isPrime = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two functions here. One to check if a number is prime and the other to display the result. Separating these makes everything much easier to manage.

```
// function to check primality and return a bool
// note that this can only accept a non optional Int so there is
// no need to check whether it is valid etc...
func checkNumberIsPrime(number: Int) -> Bool {
    // get rid of trivial examples to improve the speed later
    if number == 2 || number == 3 {
        return true
    }

    if number <= 1 || number%2 == 0 {
        return false
    }

    // square root and round up to the nearest int
    let squareRoot: Int = Int(ceil(sqrtf(Float(number))))

    // no need to check anything above sqrt of number
    // any factor above the square root will have a cofactor
    // below the square root.
    // don't need to check even numbers because we already checked for 2
    // half the numbers checked = twice as fast :-D
    for i in stride(from: 3, to: squareRoot, by: 2) {
        if number % i == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

// function on the button. Run the check and display results.
@IBAction func primeCheck(sender: AnyObject) {
    let numberInt? = numberTextField.text.toInt() // don't call a text field "number", it's just confusing.

    if let actualNumber = numberInt {
        if checkNumberIsPrime(actualNumber) {
            resultLabel.text = "\(actualNumber) is a prime number!" // don't call a label "result" call it "resultLabel". Don't confuse things.
        } else {
            resultLabel.text = "\(actualNumber) is not a prime number!"
        }
    } else {
        resultLabel.text = "'\(numberTextField.text)' is not a number!"
    }
}
```

It makes it all much easy to read and maintain.

Comment: Any reason for the incorrect down vote here? Please, show me how my code doesn't work and I'll show you that you're wrong. :)

Answer (score -1):

Well i don't know about swift, but maybe this is wrecking your code:

if numberInt! <<

To do a faster algorithm you could just search for divisors from 2 to sqrt(numberInt). (Theorem)