# Determine primes in given range

Tags: python, primes

I want to use Python to determine all prime numbers in a specified range, e.g. up to 20. I have the following code:

```
p = [ ]
for i in range(0, 20):
    for x in range(2, i):
        if i%x == 0:
            break
        else:
            p = p + [i]
            break
print p
```

The output is:

```
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

However, `15` and `9` are not primes. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else` branch is executed the moment you find a number that is not divisible by `i`. In this case that means *any odd number* is being added, as those are not divisible by `2`, but all even numbers *are*. `9` and `15` may not be primes, but they are odd.

You should only add a number if the `for` loop has tested all integers in the range, not when the `if` test fails. You can do so by *unindenting* the `else` branch so that it matches up with the `for` loop.

Instead of matching with the `if`:

```
for ...:
    if ...:
    else:
```

match with the `for` loop:

```
for ...:
    if ...:
else:
```

because then it is only executed if the `for` loop was **not** ended using a `break` statement, e.g. when all numbers were tested and did not manage to divide `x`:

```
for i in range(0, 20):
    for x in range(2, i):
        if i%x == 0:
            break
    else:
        p = p + [i]
```

Note that the `break` can then be removed from the `else` suite, as by that time you are no longer in the loop.

Note that to find a prime number, you only need to test up to the square root of that number; if a `x` is divisible by a number `i`, then it'll also be divisible by all divisors of `i`. See [Why do we check up to the square root of a prime number to determine if it is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-upto-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pri)

And adding a number to a list can be done with `list.append()` too, it is a little clearer than using the addinion operator with another list:

```
for i in range(20):
    if i < 2:
        continue  # not prime numbers either
    for x in range(2, int(i ** 0.5) + 1):
        if i % x == 0:
            # found a divisor, abort search
            break
    else:
        p.append(i)
```

Demo:

```
>>> p = []
>>> for i in range(20):
...     if i < 2:
...         continue  # not prime numbers either
...     for x in range(2, int(i ** 0.5) + 1):
...         if i % x == 0:
...             # found a divisor, abort search
...             break
...     else:
...         p.append(i)
... 
>>> p
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```