# Java code for project euler #7 gives wrong answer

Tags: java

This code is meant to find the 1001st prime but gives me the answer 47 which is clearly wrong.

```
public class problem7 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myarray = new int[1001];
        int j = 0;
        boolean prime = false;

        for (int i = 2;; i++) {
            for (int k = 2; k < i; k++) {
                if (i == (k - 1) && i % k != 0) {
                    prime = true;
                }

                if (i % k == 0) {
                    prime = false;
                    prime = true;
                }
                if (prime) {
                    myarray[j] = i;
                }
                if (j == 1000) {
                    System.out.println(myarray[1000]);
                    return;
                }

                j++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A starting point: Work on your indenting, it makes spotting errors a lot more easier ;)

Comment: What are the first few terms of myarray?

Comment: Debug and check what you are putting in `myarray`. Also, have you noticed that you are doing `prime=false;` immediately followed by `prime=true`?

Comment: @Callum I improved the program in my answer because it was simply easier to write it from scratch.

Comment: @Roberto OP is bringing their car to a mechanic, they aren't looking to buy a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I think j++ is increment only if prime number is inserted not at all case.By using this code you will be get your 1001 Prime number

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myarray = new int[1001];
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 2;; i++) {
            boolean prime = false;
            for (int k = 2; k < i; k++) {
                if (i % k == 0) {
                    prime = true;
                }
            }
            if (!prime) {
                myarray[j] = i;
                j++;
            }
            if (j == 1001) {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int primeNumber : myarray) {
            System.out.println(primeNumber);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is this upvoted and my solution is not, even though it is more efficient

Comment: @Charnjeet why are you storing the number in the array if it is not prime rather than if it is prime?

Comment: @Callum looks like his booleans need to be switched around. If when using modular division, the result is zero, the number isn't prime.

Answer (score 1):

Your check for `prime` is wrong: you cannot declare a number prime and set `prime = true` based on a single test. The inner loop should set `prime` to `false`, but it shouldn't reset it to `true`: once it's `false`, it's `false`.

The algorithm should proceed as follows:

- For each `i`, set `prime=true`
- Loop over potential divisors `k`
- If a divisor such that `i % k == 0` is found, set `prime = false`, and break the loop
- If `prime` is still `true` at the end of the nested loop, add `i` to the list of primes.

This should give you a correct result, at which point you should consider optimizing your solution using considerations below:

- If you did not find a divisor among `k` below or at `sqrt(i)`, then `i` is prime
- You do not have to try all numbers `k`, only the ones from the list of primes that you have discovered so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of dasblinkenlights algorithm!

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] primes = new int[1001];
    int i = 1;
    int index = 0;
    while (primes[1000] == 0) {
        i++;
        boolean skip = false;
        for (int i1 : primes) {
            if (i1 == 0)
                break;
            if (i % i1 == 0) { //checks if the number is a multiple of previous primes, if it is then it skips it
                skip = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!skip) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                primes[index] = i;
                System.out.println(i);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
}

static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: An algorithm made from scratch is of no help to OP. I am sure that he could find a dozen implementations in five minutes, but he's trying to get it working by himself.

Comment: Sorry, this is an implementation of your algorithm though :)

Answer (score 0):

The primality test you done here is kind of ambiguous. Because the general approach is, we pick any number assuming its prime, so at the beginning, `prime = true`. Then if there exist any factor `k` of `input` such that `k < input` and `k`then the number is not prime, so `prime = false`.

I modified your code and get a result: **`104743`** .

**Update**: Here is a bit faster way to find large prime. The inner loop will iterate up to square root of `i`, reason: [Why do we check upto the square root of a prime number to determine if it is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-upto-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pri)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] myarray = new int[10001];
    int j = 0;
    boolean prime = true;
    int i = 2;
    while (true) {
        prime = true;
        for (int k = 2; k*k <= i; k ++) {
            if (i % k == 0) {
                prime = false;
            }
        }
        if (prime) {
            myarray[j] = i;
            if (j == 10000) {
                System.out.println(myarray[10000]);
                return;
            }
            j++;
        }  
        if(i > 4)
            i += 2;
        else
            i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got that answer myself now but its still wrong

Comment: 7927 is the wrong answer

Comment: Then what is the 1001th prime?

Comment: I dont know thats what im meant to be finding out

Comment: The 1001th prime is 7927, the 1000th prime is 7919 and the 1002th prime is 7933....sigh

Comment: sorry i was meant to be finding the 10001st prime. ive changed the numbers of the array and the if statement that prints the number but the code just runs forever

Comment: I updated the answer increasing performance, check it now.