# Functional way to check primality of a number in clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

What would be a more correct functional way to write the following code which checks if a number is prime or not:

```
(defn prime? [n]
  (loop [k 2]
    (cond
     (< k n) (if (not= 0 (mod n k))
               (recur (inc k))
               (println n "is not prim"))
     :else (println n "is prim"))))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regardless of which algorithm you use to test primality, the "correct functional way" would be for your `prime?` function to return `true` or `false`. As it stands, your function returns `nil` and has side effects (prints something out).

You could then do `(println (prime? x))` to check a particular number, and have the side effects constrained to that single statement.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. What i still cant understand is that a `print` function is known to have side effects, but if we provide `print` with the same argument it will give always the same output. So why is `print` a side-effected function?

Comment: @teymuri "Output" in purely functional programming typically refers to return values. While `print` always returns `nil`, it has a side-effect (i.e. it observably does something other than computing things and returning a result) of writing to `*out*`.

Answer (score 7):

A simpler way using standard library functions such as `every?` and `range`:

```
(defn divisible? [a b]
  (zero? (mod a b)))

(defn prime? [n]
  (and (> n 1) (not-any? (partial divisible? n) (range 2 n))))
```

and refactoring I/O into a separate function for greater reuse:

```
(defn format-primality [n]
  (str n " " (if (prime? n) "is prim" "is not prim")))

(def print-primality
  (comp println format-primality))
```

Example:

```
user=> (map (fn [n] [n (prime? n)]) (range 1 15))
([1 false] [2 true] [3 true] [4 false] [5 true] [6 false] [7 true]
 [8 false] [9 false] [10 false] [11 true] [12 false] [13 true] [14 false])
```

Comment: very nice example! So would also this version (is just an alteration of yours) be a pure functional one without side effects? `(defn prime? [n]
  (if (some #(= 0 (mod n %)) (range 2 n))
    "Not prim"
    "Prim"))`

Comment: @teymuri That function always gives the same result for the same arguments, and it does not ever perform any side-effects; so yes, it is pure. FYI, in my example all functions except `print-primality` are pure.

Comment: @elyse You don't need to check till `n`. `sqrt n` is the max limit to check if the number is prime which saves a lot of time. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5811151/2610955