# What am I doing wrong here? Prime with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Updating this! I have been trying to alert out all the prime numbers up to 100 in javascript. This is what I have so far (my computer isnt allowing me to copy and paste for some reason so I have to screencap to post)
If you could guide me in the right direction, or let me know what i'm missing, that would be amazing. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your source code. Post the text of the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

A nice and typical implementation, though not the most efficient of course:

```
function primenum(num){
    if(num < 2 ) return false // 0 and 1 are not primes

    for(var i=2;i*i<=num;i++){ 

        if( num % i == 0){
            return false; // if we find a divisor up to the square of the number, then its not prime and we stop checking
        }

    }
    return true; // if we couldn´t find a divisor, then it means its a prime number
}

for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
    if(primenum(i) == true) console.log(i) // if its prime, display on console
}
```

Edit: if you want to alert all prime numbers between 1 and 100, we can store them on a array and show them later:

```
primes = [];
for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
    if(primenum(i) == true){
        primes.push(i);
    }
}
alert(primes)
```

As to why we check up to the square of the number: [Why do we check up to sqrt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-upto-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pri)

Comment: I appreciate the help, thanks! I have updated my code, but not sure how to alert it/what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: @user3247128 if you change the console.log(i) with alert(i) it will alert the prime numbers, but will give a window for each prime number, which bothers a lot. Will make an example of alerting just once storing prime numbers in array

Answer (score 0):

I have included Javascript to take input from user and find prime numbers between the chosen range.

```
  function primeNumbers(){
      var min=document.getElementById("minNumber").value;
      var max=document.getElementById("maxNumber").value;
      var Nprime=new Array();
      for(var i=min,k=0;i<=max;i++){
       if(prime(i)){
           Nprime[k]=i;
           k++;
       }   
    }
    document.write("Prime numbers are: "+Nprime);
```

}

```
   function prime(num){  
        if(num < 2 ) 
            return false; // 0 and 1 are not primes
        for(var j=2;j<=num/2;j++){ 
            if( num % j === 0){
                return false; //If we find a divisor, then return false
                }
        }
    return true; // prime number found
    }


<body>
<p> Finding prime numbers between </p> <input type="number" id="minNumber"> and <input type="number" id="maxNumber">.
<p><input type="button" value="Show now" onclick="primeNumbers()">
</body>
```