# Why is the second solution faster than the first?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, code-complexity

**First**:

```
boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return false;
    return isPrime(n, 2);
}

private boolean isPrime(int n, int i) {
    if (i == n)
        return true;
    return (n % i == 0) ? false : isPrime(n, i + 1);
}
```

**Second**:

```
boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n < 0) n = -n;
    if (n < 2) return false;
    if (n == 2) return true;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return false;

    return rec_isPrime(n, 3);
}

boolean rec_isPrime(int n, int div) {
    if (div * div > n) return true;
    if (n % div == 0) return false;
    return rec_isPrime(n, div + 2);
}
```

Please explain why is the second solution better than the first. I offered the first solution in an exam and my pointes were recudec under the claim that the solution is not effecient. I want to know what is the big differene

Comment: The second stops at the square root of n.

Comment: Also, it only tests odd divisors (except 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a test question and I always keep in mind some professors have a colorful prerogative, but i could see a few reasons one might claim the **first** is slower:

- when calculating primes you really only need to test if another primes are factors. The **second** so seeds with an odd, 3, then adds 2 ever recursive call which skips checking evens factors and reduces the numbers of calls needed by half.
- and as @uselpa pointed out, the **second** code snippet stops at the when the testing factor's square is greater than n. Which effectively means in this version that all odd's between 1 and n have been accounted for. This allows deducing n is prime faster than the **first** which counts all the way up to n before declaring prime.
- may argue that since the **first** tests for evens inside the recursive function instead of the outer method like the **second**, is it is an unnessary method on the call stack.
- I have also seem some claims that ternary operations are slower than if-else checks, so you professor may fall into this belief. [Personally, I am not convinced there is a performance difference.]

Hope this helps. Was fun to think about some primes!

Answer (score 0):

The first solution has a complexity of O(n) as it takes linear time, the second solution takes O(sqrt(n)) due to this line of code : `if (div * div > n) return true;`, because to look for a divisor past the square root is not required. For more details about that you can check : [Why do we check up to the square root of a prime number to determine if it is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-upto-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pri)