# Project Euler 3 in Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

The *Project Euler #3* asks for the largest prime factor of a given number, which I have named `num2`.

I have already solved this problem using:

```
i = 2

while num2 != 1:
    if num2 % i == 0:
        num2 /= i
    else:
        i += 1

print(i)
```

But I found this code that I cannot understand:

```
i = 2

while num2 > i ** 2:
    while num2 % i == 0:
        num2 = num2 // i
    i = i + 1

print(num2)
```

Can someone explain to me why it checks for `num2 > i * i`?

Comment: There is no point in checking for all values of `i`; once `i` is bigger than the square root of `num2` it can't be a prime factor of `num2` anymore.

Comment: @cricket_007: the input number to the problem, one would presume.

Comment: num2 is just the string name of the given number. I have set num2 = 600851475143.

Comment: Thanks for the dup link and the comments , I think I understand it now.

Comment: Some references:

[Why do we check up to the square root of a prime number to determine if it is prime or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-up-to-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pr)

/// [Prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)

/// [Integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)