# Is this c program null safe?

Tags: c

Is this is  program to print prime numbers between two numbers
a and b (null safe or not)?

if not , How to add null safe function to make it (NULL SAFE)

I have tried checking if argv[1] or argv[2] are equall to 0 
but it is not how it should work

any Ideas for this?

```
//check if a or b or both are negative numbers
int check_negative(int *x, int *y){

    if(*x<0 || *y<0)
    {
        printf("Error : One or Both arguments are Negative\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

//check if n is a prime number
int isprime(int n)
{
    int i, status = 1;

    for(i=2; i <= n/2; ++i)
    {
        if (n%i == 0)
        {
            status = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return status;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{

    if(argc==1)
    {
        printf("Error : No arguments were passed\n");
        return 0 ;
    }

    int a=atoi(argv[1]),b=atoi(argv[2]),n,status;

    if(check_negative(&a,&b)==1)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Prime numbers between %d and %d are: \n", a, b);

    for(n=a+1; n<b; ++n)
    {
       status = isprime(n);

       if(status == 1)
           printf("%d  ",n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do `check_negative` return if no number is negative? And why do you pass the arguments as pointers to the function?

Comment: Also, what happens if the user of your program pass *one* argument (i.e. `argc == 2`)?

Comment: `int a=atoi(argv[1]),b=atoi(argv[2]),n,status;` is a very weird style. also `argv[2]` is not null-checked.

Comment: For `isprime`, unless `n` is 2, you only need to check odd divisors.

Comment: You can assume that `argv[i]` is non-null if `i < argc`.  For a program that expects exactly two arguments, you need to verify that `argc==3`.

Comment: Why do you pass pointers to `check_negative` instead of the actual values?

Comment: what is "null safe" ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this c program null safe?

No.

---

The below fails when `argc < 3` (e.g. 2,1,0) as it calls `atoi()` with `NULL` or unknown. [@Ian Abbott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54182132/is-this-c-program-null-safe/54184019#comment95193203_54182132)

```
int a=atoi(argv[1]),b=atoi(argv[2]),n,status;
```

Instead change prior test from only testing against 1 to the below.  Note that `argc == 0` is possible on select platforms and with certain function calls.

```
// if(argc==1)
if(argc < 3)
```

---

As a stand-alone function, `check_negative()` does not check if a *null pointer* argument is passed before de-referencing.  Add checks

```
int check_negative(int *x, int *y){
  if (x == NULL || y == NULL) return 0;  /// or handle in some way
```

---

Aside:

`isprime(Any_int_less_than_2)` errantly returns `1`.

`for(i=2; i <= n/2; ++i)` is very slow for large `n`. Suggest speedier `for(i=2; i <= n/i; ++i)`.  [Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54160322/2410359)

Comment: Changing to `int check_negative(int x, int y);` would be another option

Comment: @M.M Yes your suggestion is better than OP's approach for this function, yet I suspect OP is delving into pointer approaches and testing for TBD reasons.