# What is the algebra that allows this optimization for prime finding?

Tags: javascript, optimization, primes

I missed this optimization in an interview and wanted to review the algebra that allows it:

```
for(let j = 2; j * j < i; j++){
```

The line above in the code below, were instead of using `j < i`, we use `j * j < i` or equivalently, [image: j < \sqrt{i}].

Is this basic algebra we learned in grade school that I forgot?  Can a reference be provided to an algebra cheat sheet or similar?

```
// prime-2
// 2 optimizations - odds and square root
function prime2(n){
  const primes = [2];

  // first optimization is to only check odd numbers ...
  not_prime: for(let i = 3; i < n; i += 2){

    // second optimization is to only check up to ...
    // the square root of j when looking for factors
    for(let j = 2; j * j < i; j++){
      if(i % j === 0){
        continue not_prime;
      }
    }
    primes.push(i);
  }
  return primes;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we check up to the square root of a prime number to determine if it is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-up-to-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pr)

Comment: I'm 100% sure there is an algebraic identity or similar for this ... I just can't recall it.

Comment: Then it sounds like this should be on [math.se] if you're specifically asking about algebra.

Comment: If n = a\*b and a <= b then a\*a <= a\*b = n

Comment: @j.a. It's from the link in the top comment.

Comment: No, this question is a duplicate and should be closed as such.  Further, the statement's truth is obvious and easily proven: pick any a > sqrt(n), and b >= a, then a*b > n, obviously.

Comment: ... express it in one way ... the idea is obvious.  Relating it to the outside world of Algebra and giving it a name is not so easy.  There is this thing called Algebra that CS uses to solve problems.  I know how it works. I want the law or identity in a single referenced form.

Comment: See here for examples ... https://www.eeweb.com/tools/algebra-reference-sheet

Comment: Should be under Algebra - radical properties ...

Comment: @avejidah I agree this should be closed, but for a different reason.  It's actually a math question, not a programming one.

Comment: @Amy Yeah, I agree with that; however, the question has been answered numerous times on math.stackexchange.com, too, directly and indirectly. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35072/calculating-prime-numbers https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343171/why-only-square-root-approach-to-check-number-is-prime/1343671#1343671

Comment: @avejidah Yes, and it's been answered several times here, too, both in these comments and below.

Answer (score 2):

LeetCode has this as a problem ([Count Primes](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-primes/)) and has a helpful hint to help you understand this:

> Let's write down all of 12's factors:
>
> 2 × 6 = 12
>
> 3 × 4 = 12
>
> 4 × 3 = 12
>
> 6 × 2 = 12
>
> As you can see, calculations of 4 × 3 and 6 × 2 are not necessary.
>   Therefore, we only need to consider factors up to √n because, if n is
>   divisible by some number p, then n = p × q and since p ≤ q, we could
>   derive that p ≤ √n.

Comment: I swear someone provided an algebraic identity for this.  Not some intuitively derived equation that makes sense.  There is an algebraic law for this.

Comment: You could read through the Wikipedia article on prime numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) to understand more about them and when this idea came up of not needing to go above the √n (found in the beginning of the History section). You can also read the "Trial division" section there (or the separate wiki page - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) to understand more about this method.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `j * j <= i`. The reasoning is that if `i` is not a prime then you have `i == p*q` where `p` is a prime smaller-or-equal `q` i.e. `p<=q`. So for example in the worst case 49 is 7*7. You don't need to check beyond `p` e.g. 7+ because you already checked for the smaller prime.

Comment: I'm 100% sure there is an algebraic identity or similar for this ... I just can't recall it.

Comment: What do you mean by worst case ... there is only 1 case.  The algorithm has only input n.  Your answer makes sense intuitively, but I'm asking for the law that proves it.