# Lisp - "when" condition executing no matter what?

Tags: conditional-statements, lisp, common-lisp, primes

I'm defining a function to test if a number is prime and I have an algorithm which works (in Python) and I have ported most of it to Lisp. The problem however is that my primality test keeps passing even when it shouldn't. For example, `isPrime(13)` still reaches the `return NIL` even though it should fail the `when` condition.

```
(defun isPrime(n)
    (cond 
        ((< n 2); numbers less than 2 aren't prime
            NIL
        )
        ((equal n 2); 2 is the only even prime
            T
        )
        ((equal (rem n 2) 0); Even numbers are never prime (besides 2)
            NIL
        )
        ((> n 2)
            (loop for i from 2 to n do(
                    when(equal (rem n i) 0);If n is evenly divisible by i, we have found a factor other than 1 and n
                        (return NIL)                   
                )
            ) 
        )
        (t T); If we get through all that with no issue, the number is prime
    )
)
```

**Question: Why does my function reach the `return NIL` branch no matter what?**

Also, if this is just a bad approach to testing primality, is there a more lisp-like way of doing this (not worried about performance, just algorithmic correctness and readability.)

Comment: `loop for i from 2 to n` is inclusive of `n`, unlike Python where `range(2,n)` goes to `n-1` only, IIRC. so you're hitting `(equal (rem n i) 0)` when `i == n`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all your code has a fairly obvious bug: once you've hit the `(> n 2)` case of the `cond` then either it's going to explicitly return `nil` or it will get to the end of the loop and ... implicitly return `nil`.  The final case of the `cond` will never be reached.

Here is a version of it which

- is formatted using standard Lisp conventions not ones imported from C or somewhere;
- uses a conventional Lisp name for the function;
- uses better operations (compare numbers with `=` not `equal`, for instance);
- uses better bounds on the loop and a better step (no need to check even numbers, you've just done that);
- fixes the bug.

```
(defun primep (n)
  (cond
   ((< n 2)
    ;; numbers less than 2 are not prime
    nil)
   ((= n 2)
    ;; 2 is prime
    t)
   ((evenp n)
    ;; even numbers are not prime
    nil)
   (t
    ;; Otherwise it is a prime if no odd integer less than or equal to
    ;; its root divides it.
    (loop for i from 3 to (isqrt n) by 2
          never (zerop (rem n i))))))
```

However a more natural way to express this in Lisp might well be to say what you would say in English:

> n is prime if it is 2 *or* if it is greater 2 *and* if it is odd, *and* if it has no odd divisors less than or equal to its square root.

Which we would write like this

```
(defun primep (n)
  (or (= n 2)                           ;2 is prime ...
      (and                              ;... otherwise ...
       (> n 2)                          ;... primes must be > 2 ...
       (oddp n)                         ;... odd ...
       ;; ... and have no odd divisorts <= their roots
       (loop for i from 3 to (isqrt n) by 2
             never (zerop (rem n i))))))
```

Finally you might want to check that the argument has a reasonable type: primality testing makes sense for natural numbers, so:

```
(defun primep (n)
  (check-type n (integer 0) "a natural number")
  (or (= n 2)                           ;2 is prime ...
      (and                              ;... otherwise ...
       (> n 2)                          ;... primes must be >= 2 ...
       (oddp n)                         ;... odd ...
       ;; ... and have no odd divisorts <= their roots
       (loop for i from 3 to (isqrt n) by 2
             never (zerop (rem n i))))))
```

Answer (score 4):

> Why does my function reach the return NIL branch no matter what?

Your loop form always return NIL.

See [22. LOOP for Black Belts](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html) for a good explanation of LOOP.

A loop form that does not accumulate a result or explicitly return a value returns NIL. A simple fix would be to return T after the loop, but there is a better way to express it:

```
(loop for i from 2 below n never (= (rem n i) 0))
```

#### Default clause

You wrote:

> If we get through all that with no issue, the number is prime

This is true but it only works for tests in the `cond` expression. Once a guard is satisfied, like `(> n 2)`, the value of the `cond` is going to be whatever value is returned by the body associated with that test. In other words, clauses don't backtrack (like in Prolog) or fall-through (like in C switches).

You could have a clause where the test could return NIL, which would make the [`COND`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_cond.htm) try the next clause:

> If there are no forms in that clause, the primary value of the test-form is returned by the cond form.

But this might be confusing.

#### Formatting

You should try to stick to the conventions of Lisp, and use what is known as `kebab-case` (dash-separated words) to name your symbols, and not leave whitespace after an open parenthesis or before a closing parenthesis.

```
(defun is-prime (n)
  (cond
    ...))
```

Personally I also like to avoid early returns when possible. In fact when possible, I find it more readable to express the result without branching (logical operators are short-circuiting, but this is a detail):

```
(defun is-prime (n)
  (and (> n 1)
       (or (= n 2)
           (loop
             for i from 2 to (isqrt n)
             never (= 0 (rem n i))))))
```

Notice that we only need to compute `i` up to the square root of `n`:

[Why do we check up to the square root of a prime number to determine if it is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-up-to-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pr)

---

edit: see also tfb's answer (start from 3 and step by 2)

Answer (score 2):

Your code will never reach the `t` condition.

`(> n 2)` makes the execution go into the `LOOP`. `COND` will then return the value of LOOP.