# I wonder what's the explanation of the for loop for(i=2; i<=Number/2; i++)

Tags: c, for-loop, conditional-statements, primes

Hi I have a code for getting prime numbers from a specific range, I'm analyzing it since its from the internet, I just wonder what the for loop `for(i=2; i<=number/2; i++);`. Why does it start with two and what's the reason behind why `i<=number/2` is the condition. Here is the full code below, I hope you can help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
  int i, Number, count, Minimum, Maximum; 

  printf("\n Please Enter the Minimum & Maximum Values\n");
  scanf("%d %d", &Minimum, &Maximum);
 
  printf("Prime Numbers Between %d and %d are:\n", Minimum, Maximum);  
  for(Number = Minimum; Number <= Maximum; Number++)
  {
    count = 0;
    for (i = 2; i <= Number/2; i++)
    {
      if(Number%i == 0)
      {
    count++;
    break;
      }
    }
    if(count == 0 && Number != 1 )
    {
       printf(" %d ", Number);
    }  
  
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it start with two and what's the reason behind why
> i<=number/2

That lower and upper bound is about performance *i.e.,* reducing the number of iterations that you need to compute.

It starts in 2 [because](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number):

> A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1

It ends in `Number/2` because if Number is a prime number until `Number/2` then after that will still be a prime number.

The reason is as follows, "If a number `n` is not a prime, it can be factored into two factors" so that `Number = a * b`. So either `a` or `b` **has to be at least 2 or larger**. Therefore, you can set the upper bound to `Number/2`.

From prime number theory we know that actually if Number is a prime number until `sqrt(Number)` then it will still be a prime number after. From [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5811176/1366871) one can read:

> If a number `n` is not a prime, it can be factored into two factors
> `a` and `b`:
>
> ```
> n = a * b
> ```
>
> Now `a` and `b` can't be both greater than the square root of `n`,
> since then the product `a * b` would be greater than `sqrt(n) * sqrt(n) = n`. So in any factorization of `n`, at least one of the
> factors must be smaller than the square root of `n`, and if we can't
> find any factors less than or equal to the square root, `n` must be a
> prime.

Answer (score 2):

`2` is the lowest possible factor of a composite (1 is a factor of primes, remember).

`Number/2` is an upper bound for the smallest factor.  I say **an** upper bound, because a better bound would be `sqrt(Number)`.  Reasoning: any factor `p` that's greater than `√N` must have a corresponding factor `q` = `N/p` which must be less than `√N`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
for (Number = Minimum; Number <= Maximum; Number++)
# This for loop is traversing all numbers in the range of the minimum and maximum number

for (i = 2; i <= Number / 2; i++)
# This for loop is checking if the number is divisible by any number starting from 2
```

For example, this can be used checking if number is prime number.

Take `i <= Number / 2` as the loop condition.

If `Number = 11` then this for loop will begin diving the number starting from 2. So the value of `i` will go from `2` to `Number / 2`, which is `5`.

This improves the performance of the loop by reducing the amount of required iterations.

Answer (score 0):

`for` loops must follow a specific structure.

The first statement (`i=2`) states that the counter must start at 2. The second statement (`i <= Number/2`) means the loop will continue whilst that statement is true. The final statement (`i++`) increments the variables `i` by 1 each time the loop runs.

So in this example, `i` starts at 2, then will increase by 1 each time until `i` is greater than `Number` before continuing to the remainder of the program.

Comment: Hi jay, thanks for the answer, but OP does not understand why it used 2 and Number/2 now how the loop works

Comment: Ah, missed that. Understood.

Answer (score 0):

First, 2 is the lowest factor of a composite while Number/2 is the highest limit in the condition starting from 2 to Number/2. We can stop at `Number/2` because if `Number` is prime until then it will still remain prime after `Number/2` to `Number` as well.

The point of using such limits is to improve performance by reducing loop count.