# Why should the loop repeat until i*i<=n for prime factorization?

Tags: algorithm

For this code, which finds the prime factors of integer n, why does the loop's integer 'i' should repeat until i*i <= n?

```
vector<int> factor(int n) {
    vector<int> ret;
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            ret.push_back(i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }
    if (n > 1) ret.push_back(n);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: what is the maximum value of a prime factor of N....it's Sqrt(n) so a faster loop is for (int i = 2;  i < Sqrt(n); i++)

Comment: @MitchWheat that statement needs to be revised. 10 has prime factor 5 which is greater that sqrt(10).

Comment: @AlbinPaul : n /= i;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we check up to the square root of a prime number to determine if it is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-up-to-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pr)

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the algorithm yourself, you would notice that once you go to a number that high, you will already have found every prime factor.

Comment: Only if you add `i` ***and*** `n / i`.

Comment: @paxdiablo, `n / i` might not be prime. And if it is, it is accounted for by the division `n /= i` and the push of the resulting `n` after the loop has finished.

Answer (score 1):

Looping until ²> is the same as looping until >√, and this is enough, because there can't be a factor  with √<<. Here is a proof:

If there were such a factor , then / is also a factor. That would be a smaller factor (/< because we said √<). But any smaller factor was already a previous value of , and so that factor was already taken out of  (by the division we have in the code).

This is a contradiction, and so there is no factor  with √<<. The only factor that remains is  itself, which is dealt with after the loop.