# Calculate the number of Primes that are less than the given Number

Tags: java, algorithm, math, primes

I'm getting desired output, but I'm not able to submit the code on the *Leetcode*.

The link of question on the [*Leetcode*](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-primes/)

*Problem statement:*

> Given an integer `n`, return the number of *prime numbers* that are
> **strictly less** than `n`.

*Constraints:*

```
0 <= n <= 5 * 10 ^ 6
```

My code:

```
class Solution {
    
    public static int count = 1;
    
    public int countPrimes(int n) {
        
        if (n == 0 || n == 1 || n == 2)
            return 0;
        else
            for (int i = 3; i < n; i++) {
                
                for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                    if (i % j == 0) {
                        break;
                    } else if (j == i - 1 && i % j != 0) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        return count;
    }
}
```

It gives the desired result all the time but when I try to submit it, it shows that only [*`4/66` tests cases are passed*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdWt4.png).

Can someone please tell me what's wrong here and why I'm not able to submit the solution?

Comment: `static int count = 1;`. Most likely the test site calls your method multiple times but you keep incrementing the shared field and returning the wrong answer for later tests.

Comment: The program only passes some testcases including the public testcases which are the ones you see but does not pass the harder testcases.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `static` variables without any good reason. `count` will live in memory until the application runs and will be effected by every invocation of `countPrimes()` with argument `n` greater than `3`. Even if *Leetcode* creates a new instance of the `Solution` for every test (*can't check it because I'm not registered there*), `static` variable would maintain the previously assigned value because it doesn't belong to any instances of `Solution`, but shared among them all.

You will definitely not encounter this issue (*but potentially there could be others related to performance*) if variable `count` would be local - i.e. declared inside the `countPrimes()`.

Condition `if (n == 0 || n == 1 || n == 2)` can be simplified to `if (n <= 2)`. And there's no need to use `else` clause because you are returning if condition matches.

Similarly, there's no need for the `else` clause in the nested loop after the `break`.

So your code can be written like this:

```
public int countPrimes(int n) {
    if (n <= 2) {
        return 0;
    }

    int count = 1;
    
    for (int i = 3; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) break;
            
            if (j == i - 1 && i % j != 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return count;
}
```

There are several enhancements we can make to improve performance.

#### Not every Number is Prime - reducing the number of iterations

As obvious, not every number is prime. The most simple observation we can make is that `2` is the only even number among primes. And if the *candidate number* is greater than `2` we can skip all even numbers by incrementing the index of the loop by `2`.

The next interesting property of primes that we can make use of is that there's no gap between the two first primes - the next prime after `2` is `3`. Which means if the *candidate number* is greater than `3` we don't need to check numbers that are divisible by `2` and by `3`.

I.e. we can omit `4` of every `6` consecutive numbers, in other words the *candidate number* can be represented as `N * 6 - 1` and `N * 6 + 1`, these pair of number will not be divisible neither by `2`, no by `3`.

To achieve that, we can initialize the loop variable to `6` - `int i = 6` and increment it at each iteration step by `6` - `i += 6`, and at every step of iteration (which would represent the next range of `6` number) we need to check the *candidate number* against two values: `i - 1` and `i + 1`.

Another improvement we can make is connected with condition `j < i`. For a large input value `n` this condition will cause a lot of fruitless iterations because there would be no prime divisors for any given number `i` greater than `sqrt(i)` [*see*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-up-to-the-square-root-of-a-number-to-determine-if-the-number-is).

And solution will be more readable if we split the method into two logical parts based on responsibilities: a method that is responsible for checking whether a *candidate number* is prime, and a method that tracks the number of discovered primes.

```
public int countPrimes(int n) {
    if (n < 3) return 0;
    if (n == 3) return 1;
    if (n == 4) return 2;

    int count = 2;

    for (int i = 6; i <= n + n % 6; i += 6) {
        if ((i - 1) < n && isPrime(i - 1)) {
            count++;
        }
        if ((i + 1) < n && isPrime(i + 1)) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

public boolean isPrime(int candidate) {
    if (candidate % 2 == 0 || candidate % 3 == 0) return false;
    if (candidate == 5) return true;
    if (candidate % 5 == 0) return false;

    boolean isPrime = true;
    double sqrt = Math.sqrt(candidate);

    for (int i = 6; i <= sqrt; i += 6) {
        if (candidate % (i - 1) == 0 || candidate % (i + 1) == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isPrime;
}
```

This solution will be faster than the initial version, but we can do better.

#### Don't recalculate the same Primes

There's no need to recalculate the same prime numbers over and over while checking a *candidate number*.

Instead, we can store every discovered prime number into a list and then check every *candidate number* against the previously encountered primes from the list.

```
public int countPrimes(int n) {
    if (n < 3) return 0;
    if (n == 3) return 1;
    if (n == 4) return 2;

    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(primes, 2, 3); // this line will be executed only if n > 4, hence we need to add primes 2 and 3 into the list
    // we don't need variable `count` anymore, instead we can check the size of primes

    for (int i = 6; i <= n + n % 6; i += 6) {
        if (i - 1 < n && isPrime(i - 1, primes)) {
            primes.add(i - 1);
        }
        if (i + 1 < n && isPrime(i + 1, primes)) {
            primes.add(i + 1);
        }
    }

    return primes.size();
}

public boolean isPrime(int candidate, List<Integer> primes) {

    boolean isPrime = true;
    double sqrt = Math.sqrt(candidate);

    for (int i = 0; i < primes.size() && primes.get(i) < sqrt; i++) {
        if (candidate % primes.get(i) == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isPrime;
}
```