# why do we use < and not <= in second loop while printing prime numbers

Tags: java

Below is the code snipent
first loop contains numbers from 1 to 100 and second loop to iterate through numbers , in second loop if we use <= prime numbers are not getting printed

```
public class primeNumbers {

 public static void main(String args[]) {
    int i, number, count;

    System.out.println("Prime Numbers from 1 to 100 are : ");
    for (number = 1; number <= 100; number++) {
        count = 0;
        for (i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0 && number != 1) {
            System.out.print(number + " ");
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: `number` is __always__ divisible by `number`. Thats why we stop one before.

Comment: Note: learn about java naming conventions. Class names go CamelCase, so always start uppercase. Also note that java isn't C, you really should declare your variables before using them.

Answer (score 1):

We know that

> Every natural number has both 1 and itself as a divisor. If it has any other divisor, it cannot be prime.

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number.

In addition to this, it is only necessary to loop from `2` until the square root of the number you are testing ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-up-to-the-square-root-of-a-number-to-determine-if-the-number-is)).

This way we can write the second loop as:

`for (i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++) {`

It is only necessary to discover if there is any natural number that is a divisor of `number` between 2 and `Math.sqrt(number)` - inclusively. If this is the case, `number` is not a prime. Otherwise it is a prime.

E.g.: Let's see the case where `number = 4`. We already know that the number 4 has 1 and itself (4) as divisors. So, we want to loop from 2 to `Math.sqrt(4) = 2` to discover if there are any more divisors. And in this case in the first iteration where `i = 2`, we find that `(4 % 2) == 0`. So 4 is not prime.

This would be written like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Prime Numbers from 1 to 100 are:");
    for (int number = 2; number <= 100; number++) {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            System.out.print(number + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

prime numbers are divisible by 1 and itself. The second loop run from 2, which means that when you check one number is divisible by itself, that does not make sense. using " < " is optimise