# Palindrome/Prime Checker in Python not working

Tags: python, algorithm, loops

My task is this:

> **What is the only (double-digit, or above) Prime number that is palindromic in both base-2 (binary), and base-10 (decimal)
>   instances?**

Whenever I run this code nothing happens, and it acts like an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong, or how can I improve?
Many thanks in advance.

```
def isPrime(n):
    if type(n) != int or n <= 1:
        return False
    elif n == 2:
        return True
    elif n%2 == 0:
        return False
    else:
        for x in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
            if n%x == 0:
                return False
                break
        return True
def isPalindrome(x):
    num = str(x)[::-1]
    if str(x) == num:
        return True
    else:
        return False
while True:
    a = 11
    if isPrime(a) and isPalindrome(a) == True:
        if isPalindrome(bin(a)) == True:
            print a
            break
    else:
        a+=2
        print a
```

**---------** **Edit: **SOLVED**** **---------**

**Revised code:**

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n < 2 or n%2 == 0:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    else:
        for x in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
            if n%x == 0:
                return False
        return True
def isPalindrome(x):
    num = str(x)[::-1]
    return str(x) == num
a = 11
while True:
    if isPrime(a) and isPalindrome(a) and isPalindrome(format(a, "b")):
            print a
            break
    a+=2
```

Thank you to all who contributed answers.

Comment: the `break` after `return` is redundant, as return already return the function value and the for finish

Comment: does it print the value of "a" or is there no output at all?

Comment: Unrelated, from [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): Use `isinstance(obj, int)` to check if `obj` is an Integer and remove `== True`.

Comment: *forehead smack* Never even thought about that. Thank you! @RubenBermudez

Comment: I believe it should print "a" after it passes both if statements in the while loop. It also should print "a" even if it doesn't pass, so I can see its progress. @Sirac

Comment: Noted. You learn something every day! @Stefan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output of `bin()` is never a palindrome, because the characters `0b` are prepended to it:

```
>>> bin(3)
'0b11'
>>> isPalindrome(bin(3))
False
```

Either slice those two characters of, or use `format()` to produce a binary representation:

```
>>> format(3, 'b')
'11'
>>> isPalindrome(format(3, 'b'))
True
```

Your loop has another problem: it won't increment if you found a palindromic prime that is **not** a palindromic prime in base 2:

```
if isPrime(a) and isPalindrome(a) == True:
    if isPalindrome(format(a, 'b')) == True:
        print a
        break
    # no else here
else:
    a+=2
    print a
```

Just test for all conditions in one test:

```
if isPrime(a) and isPalindrome(a) and isPalindrome(format(a, 'b')):
    print a
    break
a += 2
```

There is **rarely** a need to test for `== True` in a boolean test.

Next is that you **reset** `a` in the loop:

```
while True:
    a = 11
```

It doesn't matter what you do to `a` in the rest of the loop, at the top it goes back to 11. Move that out of the loop:

```
a = 11
while True:
    if isPrime(a) and isPalindrome(a) and isPalindrome(format(a, 'b')):
        print a
        break
    a += 2
```

Whenever you write `if comparison: return True` followed by `else: return False`, *just return the test instead*:

```
def isPalindrome(x):
    num = str(x)[::-1]
    return str(x) == num
```

because the `==` comparison operator already returns a boolean value.

Your primality test doesn't need to test for the type of `n`, really (you only ever pass in integers), but the correct way to test for a type is to use:

```
isinstance(n, int)
```

as this allows for subclasses of `int` too. Even if you *do* need to limit something to a very specific type and cannot allow for subclasses, you'd use:

```
type(n) is int
```

as types are singletons.

Taking advice from [isPrime Function for Python Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285534/isprime-function-for-python-language) your `isPrime()` function would be a little faster if you used:

```
def isPrime2(n):
    if n < 2: return False
    if n == 2: return True
    for i in range(3, int(n ** 0.5) + 1, 2):   # only odd numbers
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

instead.

Your loop could be made more efficient by limiting the number of values you look at. If you look at the [Palindronic Prime series](http://oeis.org/A002385) on the OEIS you'll see that apart from 11, **all** base-10 palindromic primes have an odd number of digits, so you can skip large swathes of numbers. The following would produce better candidates:

```
def palindromic_candidates():
    yield 11
    outer = 1
    while True:
        for i in range(10):
            yield int('{}{}{}'.format(outer, i, str(outer)[::-1]))
        outer += 1
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> pc = palindromic_candidates()
>>> list(islice(pc, 30))
[11, 101, 111, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 202, 212, 222, 232, 242, 252, 262, 272, 282, 292, 303, 313, 323, 333, 343, 353, 363, 373, 383]
>>> list(islice(pc, 100, 130))
[13931, 14041, 14141, 14241, 14341, 14441, 14541, 14641, 14741, 14841, 14941, 15051, 15151, 15251, 15351, 15451, 15551, 15651, 15751, 15851, 15951, 16061, 16161, 16261, 16361, 16461, 16561, 16661, 16761, 16861]
```

Use this instead of your `while True` loop, remove the `a += 2` line:

```
for a in palindromic_candidates():
    if isPrime(a) and isPalindrome(format(a, 'b')):
        print a
        break
```

where you can drop the test for base-10 palindromes as the generator produces *only* palindromes.

Comment: With the `a=11` inside the while loop, it is always checked if number `11` is prime, palindrome and palindrome in binary. And if it isn't `13` is printing and check again for `11`. `a=11` should be outside the while loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You've used the site longer than me, would a question like this (where there are many, many things to address) be considered off-topic?

Comment: @AlexThornton: Not really; the OP isn't asking multiple questions here. There is just more than one problem to address that they weren't aware of.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wow - was unaware I had so many problems! Being the unexperienced 14 year old that I am that should have been expected. Thank you for taking the time to type out such a clear and detailed response, it was very helpful. Will post finished code for the heck of it.