# Find prime numbers in range

Tags: python, primes

```
def is_prime(number):
    for i in range(2, number):
        if number % 1 == 0 and number % i == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
print(is_prime(13))       
print(is_prime(55)) #True ##Why ???
def prime_numbers(a, b):
    lst = []
    for i in range(a,b+1):
        if is_prime(i):
            lst.append(i)
    return lst

print(prime_numbers(50, 100))
```

This is my code and suppose I have `prime_numbers(50, 100)`.

It should return `[53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]` instead of

`[51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99]`.

So what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [isPrime Function for Python Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285534/isprime-function-for-python-language)

Comment: But you return `True` far to eagerly.

Comment: This has already been answered below, but I'd just add that there's no point in iterating over the range `(2, number)`. You only need to go as far as half of `number` as any number greater than that cannot divide evenly into `number`. I'd probably also make sure that `number` is an integer otherwise the `range` is likely to throw an error.

Comment: Dont think number%1==0 is needed, it is always True. To make it more efficient only go upto square root of the number + 1 (1 added to make sure you go upto the next integer when sqrt returns a float)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relocate the `return True` line:

```
def is_prime(number):
    for i in range(2, number):
        if number % 1 == 0 and number % i == 0:
            return False

    return True 


print(is_prime(13)) # True  
print(is_prime(55)) # False
```

Your code isn't working because you return `True` or `False` during the first iteration.

Comment: then print(is_prime(13))  will be false as well

Comment: which should be True for this case

Comment: @user3419984 no, `is_prime(13)` is True