# listing prime numbers from 3 to 21 in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for x in range (3,21):
    if(x%2==0):
        print (x,'is a not a prime number')
    else:
        print (x,'is a prime number')
```

This is my code but when it prints it says `9 is a prime number` and `15 is a prime number`.

Which is wrong because they aren't so how do I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find prime numbers in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079761/find-prime-numbers-in-range)

Comment: Your code does nothing to test for prime numbers. It is looking at whether a number is odd or even

Comment: Possible duplicate of [isPrime Function for Python Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285534/isprime-function-for-python-language)

Comment: your logic finds even and odds not prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.

```
def isPrime(N):
    i = 2
    while i**2 <= N:
        if N % i == 0:
            return False
        i+=1
    return True

for i in range(3, 21 + 1):
    if isPrime(i):
        print(i, 'is prime')
    else:
        print(i, 'is not a prime number')
```

First of all, create a function for determining whether or not a given number is prime (this is not a requirement but just a good practice). That function is not that hard: it just starts at `i = 2` (starting at 1 makes no sense because every number can be divided by it) and check if N can be divided by it. If that is the case, we have found a divisor of N and thus, it isnt prime. Otherwise, continue with the next number: `i += 1`. The most tricky part of the loop is the stoping condition: `i**2 <= N`: we dont have to look further, because if some `j > i` is a divisor of N, then there is some other `k < i` that is also a divisor of N: `k * j == N`. If such k exists, we will find it before getting to the point where `i * i == N`. Thats all. After that, just iterate over each number you want to check for primality.

Btw, the best way to check for the primality of a set of number is using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: thank you!  do you mind explaining how this works really quickly? Like why the +1 in the range and what the first part is? Sorry I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: @BrendoCampos I edited the answer explaining what that code does. The +1 in the range is just to ensure that 21 is included in the checks, because `range(3, 21)` returns an open interval on the right: **[3, 21)**

Answer (score 0):

Your code only checks if a number is even. All odd numbers are not prime. So write a for-loop that checks if a odd number is divisible by any of the odd number less than that. Sometying like:

For i in (3 to n): If n mod i == 0, n is not prime.

Comment: I know the issue is with the if loop, but every other method of finding a prime number ends up messing up the whole list somehow. When I run the program I want it to say '3 is a prime number' '4 is not a prime number' all the way to 20 all at once