# Function to check if number x is prime in python

Tags: python

What I've done so far is:

```
def check_prime(x):
  if x >= 2:
    for n in range(2, x - 1):
      if x % n == 0:
        return False
      else:
        return True
  else:
    return False
```

However when I check if any number >= 2 is a prime it returns `None` instead of `True` or `False`. `check_prime(0)` returns `False` and `check_prime(1)` returns `False`. Why does any number >= 2 return `None` and how can I fix this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [isPrime Function for Python Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285534/isprime-function-for-python-language)

Comment: range (2,1) and range (2,2) are going to skip the for loop body

Comment: The best thing to do is not write your own. `pyprimes` is pip-installable and includes `pyprimes.is_prime()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1:** The problem is `range(n, x-1)`.

If your input is 2 or 3, `range(2, x-1)` will be an empty list since the second parameter of `range` is exclusive.

Since you're only returning inside the for loop and it never gets there, it returns None (i.e. it returns nothing).

**Problem 2:** Aside from never entering the for loop if `x = 2` or `x = 3`, your code has some issues.

As you've written it, it will return in the first iteration. Certainly, if `x % n == 0` you know `x` is not prime and can return `False`. But even if `n` is not a factor of `x`, you still have to check the other potential factors.

You should return `True` outside of the for loop, not inside it.

**Solution:**

```
if x == 2: return True
if x%2 == 0 or x < 2: return False
for n in range(3, x/2, 2):
  if x % n == 0:
    return False
return True
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is wrong because you should not return True in the loop (in your code the loop will always run once).

```
def check_prime(x):
    if x >= 2:
        for n in range(2, x ):
            if (x % n) == 0:
                return False
        #after the complete for n loop
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Checkout a working fiddle: http://pythonfiddle.com/check-prime

Besides all that you can obtimize your code (if you like) by taking the square root of `x` (round up) as the end point for your loop (do not forget +1 since `range` is not inclusive). Since you will get the mirrored options once your past the square root. (6×4 = 4*6 = 20. Square root of 20 is 5).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fixed code. You had multiple issues in it, namely:

1. When number was `2` for example, you went into the `if` cycle, however your loop did not execute and therefore you got `None` as a result.
2. `range(start, end)` does not include the `end`, therefore you have do not have to write `end - 1`.
3. You need to check for every number up to `n` (well, you don't have to when you optimize your code `:)`), however if I had a number like 99 = 3 * 33, it would not be divisible by 2 and would classify it as a prime despite being a composite number.

You can do a number of basic optimalizations such as check numbers up to `sqrt(n)`, check if number is divisble by 2 to discard half of the choices, etc.

'

```
def check_prime(x):
    for n in range(2, x):
        if x % n == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a kludge-tastic way of doing it...

```
def prime(x):

    factors = []
    if x <= 0:
        return False
    if x == 1:
        return False
    if x == 2:
        return True
    for n in range(2, x):
        if x % n == 0:
            factors.append(n)

    if len(factors) != 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```