# Python is_prime

Tags: python, primes

Assume the availability of a function `is_prime`. Assume a variable  n has been associated with positive integer. Write the statements needed to compute the sum of the first n prime numbers. The sum should be associated with the variable  total.

Note: `is_prime` takes an integer as a parameter and returns True if and only if that integer is prime.

So far I have:

```
i=2
count=0
total=0
while (count<n):
    if(is_prime(i)):
        total+=1
        count+=1
    i+=1
```

Where am I missing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, was in process of editing when you did.

Comment: you dont have a function and its not returning ... plus you should probably be adding `i` `total += i`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [isPrime Function for Python Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285534/isprime-function-for-python-language)

Comment: @Anil_M i think he has an `is_prime` method provided to him ... (he isnt trying to write is_prime)

Answer (score 1):

to fix your existing ... just add `i` to `total`

```
i=2
count=0
total=0
while (count<n):
    if(is_prime(i)):
        total+=i
        count+=1
    i+=1
print total
```

you could make it much better by making a generator to yield primes forever

```
def primes():
   for i in itertools.count(1):
       if is_prime(i):
          yield i
```

then you could make `n_primes` that yields the first `n` primes

```
def n_primes(n):
    return [prime for prime,_ in zip(primes(),range(n))]
```

then lastly you just sum it

```
print sum(n_primes(N))
```

Comment: Thank Joran, I knew I was overlooking something so simple.