# How to improve this function to determine a prime?

Tags: python, performance, math, numbers, theory

I was asked this problem in an interview a few days ago and wanted to improve on the solution I had given during it. So far this is what I have. Not sure how to go about making it more efficient. I guess for starters:

1) Does adding the i%2 == 0 line save time?

2) What is the time complexity of the % operator in python? Is there a way to check if a number is divisible by some faster way without using %?

3) The d <= math.sqrt(i) makes use of the fact that it is useless to compute divisors past the square root of i, as d will not divide i nicely until d=i. Does this present the optimal number of steps?

4) I start at d=3 because it's a given that i is odd

5) Going off the 4th point, I increment by 2 instead of 1, since it is a given that i is odd.

```
def is_prime(i):
    if i < 2:
        return False
    if i == 2:
        return True 
    d = 3
    if i%2 == 0: #skip even numbers 
        return False 
    while d <= math.sqrt(i):
        if i%d == 0:
            return False
        d += 2
    return True
```

Comment: Might be better suited to Code Review stackexchange. Similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15285588/314291). Yes, the  %2 ==0 is generally beneficial. This approach can be extended to higher primes such as 3, 5 etc, and optimized as a 'wheel of 6 / 30 / 120' etc. You can also build a cache of the first N primes as an optimization.

Answer (score 0):

1) in theory no, but in practice yes. It does not reduce time complexity in `O` notation, but can reduce in practice as you do not consider even numbers. Hence, this program could be 2 times faster.

2) as mentioned in comment, it is generally beneficial.

3) Of course. you have just considered `sqrt(i)` which reduces time complexity from `O(i)` to `O(sqrt(i))`.

4) it is not a question. However, it is true.

5) Again, it is not a question. However, it is reasonable, as you have checked `i` is not even.