# How do i check if the number is semi prime

Tags: python, if-statement, range

```
def is_prime(num):

    if num > 1:

        for i in range(2,num):
```

## return False if (num % i) == 0:

```
            if (num % i) == 0:
                return False
```

## return True if prime

```
        else:
            return True
```

## return False if not prime

```
    else:
        return False

def is_semiprime():
        n = int(input("Enter a number to find out if its semiprime or not\n>>> "))
        for d1 in range(2, int(n**.5)):
            if n % d1 == 0:
                d2 = int(n / d1)
```

## is_prime(d1) and is_prime(d2) go through and don't tell me there true or false they just send blank lines.

```
               return is_prime(d1) and is_prime(d2)
            return False

is_semiprime()
```

## when it Returns is_prime(d1) and is_prime(d2) if they are both True then return True

Comment: Is your problem (a) that you don't know what semiprimes are, (b) that you don't know an algorithm to test for semiprimes, or (c) that you do, but you're stuck on some particular step in implementing it? If it's (c), show us the code you _do_ know how to write, and point out the gap (like `count += 1 # I know I need to do count += n if i**n divides num but I don't know how to get n`).

Comment: Write a function that just checks whether a number is prime. Write another function that gets the two factors of a number, and calls the `isPrime()` function on both of them. If they're both true, the number is semiprime.

Comment: @Barmar What are “the two factors” of 60? Or 5?

Comment: @abarnert If the number is not prime, you should be able to find a factor. Divide the number by that factor to get the other factor. Then check whether both of these are prime.

Comment: @Barmar (b) I Don't know an algorithm to test for semi primes. Also a semi prime number is a number made up of two primes so how do i code it to check for that

Comment: I just told you the algorithm to test for semi primes. Find one divisor of the number. Divide the number by that to get a second divisor. Test whether both divisors are prime. That's all there is to it.

Comment: oh ok sorry thanks didnt see that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A semi-prime number is a number that's the product of two prime numbers. So the algorithm is simple:

1. Find one divisor of the number, call it `d1`.
2. Divide the number by `d1` to get a second divisor, `d2`.
3. Test whether both `d1` and `d2` are prime. If they are, then the original number is semi-prime.

Code:

```
def is_semiprime(n):
    for d1 in range(2, int(n**.5)+1):
        if n % d1 == 0:
            d2 = n / d1
            return is_prime(d1) and is_prime(d2)
    return False

def is_prime(n):
  if n == 2 or n == 3: return True
  if n < 2 or n%2 == 0: return False
  if n < 9: return True
  if n%3 == 0: return False
  r = int(n**0.5)
  f = 5
  while f <= r:
    if n%f == 0: return False
    if n%(f+2) == 0: return False
    f +=6
  return True    

def ask_semiprime():
    num = int(input("What number would you like to check?"))
    if is_semiprime(num):
        print(num, " is semiprime")
    else:
        print(num, " is not semiprime")

ask_semiprime()
```

I copied the `is_prime` function from [isPrime Function for Python Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285534/isprime-function-for-python-language?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: yep i have a prime function

Comment: so my code wont report to me if the imputed number is semi prime.

Comment: `if is_semiprime(number): print(number, " is semiprime")`

Comment: my code above was changed though that wont work. well idk were to put it in my code lol

Comment: You need to learn to separate functions that perform input and output from functions that compute results.

Comment: oh well i just dont get why it passed P and adds 2 sometimes not all the time

Comment: What is `P`, and why are you testing it in your `elif` statement?

Comment: `is_prime()` needs to return `True` or `False` to indicate whether `num` is prime or not. It shouldn't print anything.

Comment: im testing it in elif statement because when is_prime(d1), is_prime(d2) go through to the els statment in is_prime it is suposed to add up to 4 which tells me that the inputed number is semiprime.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing at all. Stop using global variables, use parameters and return values. `is_semiprime()` calls `is_prime()` twice, they'll each set `P` differently. You only initialize `P` once, at the beginning of the script, so each time you call `is_prime()` it increments it from where it left off before.

Comment: But your version of `is_semiprime()` doesn't even use the result of `is_prime()`. It needs to test if it's true of both `d1` and `d2`.

Comment: What does adding up to 4 have to do with whether a number is semiprime? I think you're very confused about what "semiprime" means.

Comment: You need to write a self-contained function called `is_prime(num)` that just returns `True` or `False`. The function you've written doesn't work like that. Once you've done that, my `is_semiprime()` function will work. If you're having trouble with that, it's a separate question.

Comment: A code that will factor any number inputted and report to the user if the number was, semi prime.

this i what i have to do and it is for school. No one has completed it

Comment: I know what a semiprime number is. the problem is that i cant make it tell me the number inputed is semi prime, returning true or false sends a blank line lol

Comment: I've added all the other functions you need.

Comment: btw what version of python are you because it tells me 49 is not semi prime when it is

Comment: Sorry, thought the factors had to be different, so I wasn't including `n**.5` in the range checked. I changed it to `range(2, int(n**.5)+1)` and now it works.

Comment: ah ok cool I also changed the false in is_semiprime(n) to Capital False

Answer (score 1):

number=int(input())

s=number

x=[]

for i in range(2,number+1):

```
if s%i==0:

    x.append(i)

    s=s//I

    if s==i or (i>s and s!=1):

        x.append(s)
```

if len(x)==2:

```
print(f"{number} is a semiprime number because it is the product of Tow primes: ",end="")
```

else:

```
print(f"{number} is not a semiprime number because it is the product of {len(x)} primes: ",end="")
```

for i in x:

```
if i==x[-1]:

    print(i)

else:

    print(str(i)+"*",end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def check_prime(n): #for checking wheather prime or not
    if n > 1:
        if n == 2: return True
        for i in range(2,n):
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
                break
        return True
    return False
def primeproduct(m): #for checking wheather prime product or not 
    if m >= 0:
      for i in range(1,m):
        if m%i == 0 and check_prime(i) and check_prime(m//i):
            return True
            break
    return False
```

*this may help*