# Finding 6648031207514 ' s largest prime factor

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

this is my first question here.

I have been solving eulerproject.net questions and after getting a correct answer for the given input 
I wanted to try different ones to check whether my code was working properly. Seems like it doesn't.

Largest prime factor should be 1137193159 but I get 79. Of course because of the upper limit I have put 
here. However, if I increase the upper limit even a little my code gets super slow.

This is the function I have used for finding the largest prime factor

```
def largest_prime_factor(n) :

upper_limit = math.trunc((n**0.5))

while(1) : 

    for num in range(upper_limit, 2, -1) : 
        if n % num == 0 :
            if(isPrime(num)) : 
                return num 
        else : 
            pass

    if(isPrime(n)) : 
        return n
```

Here is the isprime method

```
## taken from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285534/isprime-function-for-python-language
def isPrime(n):
if n==2 or n==3: return True
if n%2==0 or n<2: return False
for i in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):   # only odd numbers
    if n%i==0:
        return False    

return True
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can change the `isPrime()` method, by using sieve of erastosthenes. Since you're only checking root(n) numbers, you'll have to create a sieve of size root(n). Then your time complexity will come down to O(root(n)) from O(n).

Comment: @Mooncrater--[Complexity of Sieve of Erastosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithmic_complexity) is O(n log log n), which makes it good for finding all primes in a range.  Considering this overhead how is the complexity reduced to O(sqrt(n)) for finding the largest prime factor for one number using the sieve?  Meaning is_prime would become O(1) using a list of primes, but it first incurred the O(n*log log n) overhead to find all the primes.

Comment: Yeah man you get the point.

Comment: I created a custom factorization module that use Sieve of Erastohenes and is non probabilistic. It can also reduce larger numbers that PARI/ECM can't factor via straight factorization, but is can be reduced using the pseudoprimes it creates on PARI/ECM so used in conjunction you can reduce the number 2*1200-1, which you can't quickly do straight up using PARI/ECM. If your interested in it you can find it here: https://github.com/oppressionslayer/primalitytest/   It also includes a super fast modulus reduction technique for powers of two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixes to software

- The Largest prime factor can be greater than sqrt(n).  Software only returns up to sqrt(n)
- incorrect range 'range(upper_limit, 2, -1) :' should be `for num in range(upper_limit, 1, -1) :` since stop point is exclusive
- Should not have while loop around for loop
- No need to check if the number is prime after for loop

**Issue**

Above Fixes Code, but Remaining Issue is algorithm complexity will be O(n) since

1. O(sqrt(n)) size of for loop
2. O(sqrt(n)) to run is_prime in each loop
3. 1&2 makes complexity O(n)

**Refactored Code**

```
import math

def largest_prime_factor(n) :

  upper_limit = math.trunc((n**0.5))

  for num in range(upper_limit, 1, -1) : # use 1 for lower limit
      if n % num == 0 :
          if(isPrime(num)) : 
              return max(num, n // num)  # to include values above sqrt(n)

  #if(isPrime(n)) : 
  return n  # We know it's prime since no divisors in for loop

def isPrime(n):
  if n==2 or n==3: return True
  if n%2==0 or n<2: return False
  for i in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):   # only odd numbers
      if n%i==0:
          return False    

  return True
```

**Usage**

```
print(largest_prime_factor(1137193159 )) # Output: 1137193159 
# Timing (using timeit):  0.01357 seconds per calculation
```

**Better Algorithm (closer to O(sqrt(n)*log(n)) Time Complexity**

[Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-find-largest-prime-factor-of-a-number/)

Advantage

- Sieve of Erastosenes is better for a batch of numbers --O(n log log n) to find primes in range, then log (n) per number. This wold be O(n*log(n)) for a single number.
- Current algorithm is better for a single number--no setup, so O(sqrt(n)*log(n)) per number.

  ## A function to find largest prime factor

  def max_prime_factor(n):

  ```
  # Initialize the maximum prime factor 
  # variable with the lowest one 
  maxPrime = -1

  # Remove factors of two 
  while n % 2 == 0: 
    max_prime = 2
    n //= 2

  # Removed all factors of two so n is odd 
  # For loop size sqrt(n) / 2 
  for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2): 
    while n % i == 0: 
                    # O(log(n)) divisors
      max_prime = i # i must be prime since all 
                    # the lower prime divisors 
                    # of n have been factored out
      n //= i 

  # Check if
  # n is a prime number  
  if n > 2: 
    max_prime = n 

  return max_prime
  ```

**Comparison**

Timing for n = 1137193159

- max_prime_factor: .0061 seconds
- largest_prime_factor: 0.01357 seconds

Thus: ~2X improvement for this case over the original code