# Function displays nothing after returning

Tags: python

```
 import math


def erathosthene(n):
    
    for d in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n) + 0.5)):
        while n % d != 0:
            d =+ 1
        if n % d == 0:
            print('this number isn\'t prime')
            return False
        else:
            print('this number is prime')
            return True
```

erathosthene(35)

it literally display nothing and honestly idk why it display nothing

[there's nothing after return in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4hvx.png)

Comment: There is no print. so nothing is displayed

Comment: Also with 6, the loop doesn't generate any value, so nothing is returned from the method

Comment: What did you expect from that code to do ?

Comment: I tried with print I returned nothing either

Comment: Ok so I just chose for example 19 instead of 6 ?

Comment: What do you expect that code to do ?

Comment: It should return "True" if n is prime and False if it's not

Comment: An integer n is prime if d varying from 2 at √n n checks the condition: As long as it is not divisible by d, we increment the value of d. If n is divisible by d then n is not first. And of course, if n is not divisible by any of the values ​​taken by d, then n is prime

Comment: Ow get it, I answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is a primality test and the problems of your code are

- let the `for` loop increase `d`, don't increase it by yourself too
- if `n` is divisible by `d` then you end as it is not prime
- if `n` is NOT divisible by the current `d`, that **doesn't** mean it is prime, you wait to wait
- loop until `sqrt(x)+1` not `sqrt(x)+0.5`, because for
- add condition for numbers `< 2`

```py
def erathosthene(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    for d in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n) + 1)):
        if n % d == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Then call with a `print` so your code displays something

```
print(erathosthene(6))
```

---

For better implementation, you can see [isPrime Function for Python Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285534/isprime-function-for-python-language/15285588) for example