# Check prime number with Define Function in Python

Tags: python, function

I've created a function in python to check whether a manually inputed number is a prime number or not. The code lines are showed as follow:

```
def checkIfPrime(numberToCheck):
    for x in range(2,numberToCheck):
        if (numberToCheck%x==0):
            return False
        return True

answer=checkIfPrime(int(input('Enter your number to check if it is a prime number:')))
print(answer)
```

When I run the module in IDLE Shell with numbers from 12 to 19. All results are correct except the input number 15. The module returns True when number 15 is entered. Since 15 can be divided by 3 and 5 with no remainder, 15 is not a prime number and the result is supposed to be False.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7g9z.png)

I don't know where lies the problem and cause the incorrect result.
I'd appreciate any help:)

Comment: `if (15%2==0):` will be false and return false, no more check will be done.

Comment: Check the indentation of your `return True` statement. Are you sure it should be inside the for-loop?

Comment: Now's a good time to learn [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
and
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Stepping through your code will make give you an understanding of where (and why) it misbehaves and what you need to do to fix it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [isPrime Function for Python Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285534/isprime-function-for-python-language)

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkIfPrime(numberToCheck):
    for x in range(2,numberToCheck):
        if (numberToCheck%x==0):
            return False
        return True
```

is the same as writing

```
def checkIfPrime(numberToCheck):
    for x in range(2,numberToCheck):
        return not numberToCheck%x==0
```

At the first return the for loop breaks.

Perhaps you wanted to write:

```
def checkIfPrime(numberToCheck):
    for x in range(2,numberToCheck):
        if (numberToCheck%x==0):
            return False
    return True
```

This means that you can't divide the number by any other number between 2 and itself, so you check all numbers and only if none meets the criteria you return True.

Answer (score 0):

When you return `True`, make sure to not do it in the for loop, or every time, it will return `True` if the number isn't divisible by 2. Here is the updated code with the fixed indentation:

```
def checkIfPrime(numberToCheck):
    for x in range(2, numberToCheck):
        if (numberToCheck % x == 0):
            return False
    return True

while True:
    answer = checkIfPrime(int(input('Enter your number to check if it is a prime number:')))
    print(answer)
```