# Sieve Of Atkin Implementation in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to implement the algorithm of Sieve of Atkin given in Wikipedia Link as below:

[Sieve Of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin)

What I've tried so far is the implementation in Python given by following Code:

```
import math
is_prime = list()
limit = 100
for i in range(5,limit):
    is_prime.append(False)

for x in range(1,int(math.sqrt(limit))+1):
    for y in range(1,int(math.sqrt(limit))+1):
        n = 4*x**2 + y**2

        if n<=limit and (n%12==1 or n%12==5):
            # print "1st if"
            is_prime[n] = not is_prime[n]
        n = 3*x**2+y**2
        if n<= limit and n%12==7:
            # print "Second if"
            is_prime[n] = not is_prime[n]
        n = 3*x**2 - y**2
        if x>y and n<=limit and n%12==11:
            # print "third if"
            is_prime[n] = not is_prime[n]

for n in range(5,int(math.sqrt(limit))):
    if is_prime[n]:
        for k in range(n**2,limit+1,n**2):
            is_prime[k] = False
print 2,3
for n in range(5,limit):
    if is_prime[n]: print n
```

Now I get error as

```
is_prime[n] = not is_prime[n]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

this means that I am accessing the value in list where the index is greater than length of List. Consider the Condition when x,y = 100, then of-course the condition n=4x^2+y^2 will give value which is greater than length of list. Am I doing something wrong here? Please help.

**EDIT 1**
As suggested by Gabe, using

```
is_prime = [False] * (limit + 1)
```

insted of :

```
for i in range(5,limit):
    is_prime.append(False)
```

did solved the problem.

Comment: The Code is working fine when added the line as suggested by gabe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem is that your limit is 100, but your `is_prime` list only has `limit-5` elements in it due to being initialized with `range(5, limit)`.

Since this code assumes it can access up to `limit` index, you need to have `limit+1` elements in it: `is_prime = [False] * (limit + 1)`

Note that it doesn't matter that `4x^2+y^2` is greater than `limit` because it always checks `n <= limit`.

Comment: I added range(5, limit+1) while appending in is_prime and yet receive the error.

Comment: `range(x, y)` returns `y-x` elements, so your `is_prime` list will be indexed from 0 to 95. You need it to be indexed from 0 to 101. Use `is_prime = [0] * (limit + 1)` to create the list.

Comment: Gabe can you refer.to the link given in wikipedia. It has given range 1 to 95 including both

Comment: They initialize their list with `False`, not `0`, so it should probably be `[False] * (limit + 1)`. (Not that it makes a difference with the implementation, but it should make it more similar to the original)

Comment: @SarvagyaPant: Do you understand that in Python lists always start out at index 0? No matter what number you put in your `range()` call, the very first time you call `is_prime.append()`, you are creating an index 0. The 95th time you call `is_prime.append()`, you are making the list 95 elements long regardless of the fact that `i` is 100!

Comment: So silly of me. I got it. I will check the program again with correction.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution

```
import math

def sieveOfAtkin(limit):
    P = [2,3]
    sieve=[False]*(limit+1)
    for x in range(1,int(math.sqrt(limit))+1):
        for y in range(1,int(math.sqrt(limit))+1):
            n = 4*x**2 + y**2
            if n<=limit and (n%12==1 or n%12==5) : sieve[n] = not sieve[n]
            n = 3*x**2+y**2
            if n<= limit and n%12==7 : sieve[n] = not sieve[n]
            n = 3*x**2 - y**2
            if x>y and n<=limit and n%12==11 : sieve[n] = not sieve[n]
    for x in range(5,int(math.sqrt(limit))):
        if sieve[x]:
            for y in range(x**2,limit+1,x**2):
                sieve[y] = False
    for p in range(5,limit):
        if sieve[p] : P.append(p)
    return P

print sieveOfAtkin(100)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the optimized implementation proposed by Zsolt KOVACS:

```
import math
import sys

def sieveOfAtkin(limit):
    P = [2,3]
    r = range(1,math.isqrt(limit)+1)
    sieve=[False]*(limit+1)
    for x in r:
        for y in r:
            xx=x*x
            yy=y*y
            xx3 = 3*xx
            xx3yy = xx3 + yy            
            n = xx3yy + xx
            if n<=limit and (n%12==1 or n%12==5) : sieve[n] = not sieve[n]
            n = xx3yy
            if n<=limit and n%12==7 : sieve[n] = not sieve[n]
            n = xx3 - yy
            if x>y and n<=limit and n%12==11 : sieve[n] = not sieve[n]
    for x in range(5,int(math.sqrt(limit))):
        if sieve[x]:
            xx=x*x
            for y in range(xx,limit+1,xx):
                sieve[y] = False
    for p in range(5,limit):
        if sieve[p] : P.append(p)
    return P

primes = sieveOfAtkin(int(sys.argv[1]))    
print (primes)
```

You pass upper limit as the first argument. This program runs in about 6s on my machine compared to the original which runs in 21s for 10 million limit. What I did:

- replaced exponentiation with multiplication
- precalculated some multiplications

Edit: I removed the calculation of the second n and sped up the code slightly:

19.61s vs 21.11s  for 50M limit

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "-_-", line 28, in <module>
    primes = sieveOfAtkin(int(sys.argv[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Have you passed the first argument which is the upper limit?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for very interesting question!

Because bugs in your code are already fixed by other answers, so I decided to implement from scratch my own very optimized versions of [Sieve of Atkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) and also [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) (for comparison).

It appears that out of 4 functions that I implemented best one is **193 times** faster than your original code, incredible speedup! If on my slow laptop 10 Million limit takes 50 seconds in your code, same limit takes just 0.26 seconds in my function.

Best speedup in my code is achieved with help of [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) and [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) packages. They are only used to speedup run of code (with the help of pre-compilation), but I didn't use any scientific functions from these packages.

First I'll show timings, this is console output if you run my code located at end of post.

```
Limit 10_000_000
SieveOfAtkin_Mahadeva           : time  50.513 sec, boost    1.00x
SieveOfAtkin_bergee             : time  13.016 sec, boost    3.88x
SieveOfEratosthenes_Arty_Python : time   5.768 sec, boost    8.76x
SieveOfAtkin_Arty_Python        : time   3.632 sec, boost   13.91x
SieveOfEratosthenes_Arty_Numba  : time   0.445 sec, boost  113.51x
SieveOfAtkin_Arty_Numba         : time   0.261 sec, boost  193.54x
```

Besides my 4 functions, I used original Questioner's [code of @Mahadeva](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21783160/941531) and best (speed wise) answer's [code of @bergee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71490622/941531).

I did 2 versions of Atkin function (first in pure Python, second with use of Numba and Numpy), and 2 versions of Sieve of Eratosthenes (same, one in pure Python, anothe with Numba/Numpy).

Also I did following optimizations, you may find them out if you read official [Atkin Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin#Pseudocode) (pseudocode section):

1. Instead of computing X and Y loops both till `Sqrt(limit)` with step 1, according to Wiki you may do step of 2 in half of loops.
2. Also if you do some homework math then it is easy to see that X loop doesn't need to be run till `Sqrt(limit)`, but instead first X loop can be run till `Sqrt(limit / 4)`, second X loop till `Sqrt(limit / 3)`, third X loop till `Sqrt(limit / 2)`. These all can be derived from reversing a term `4 * x * x` and `3 * x * x`.
3. Also Wikipedia says that it is not needed to process ALL values of `n % 12 == 1 or n % 12 == 5` and `n % 12 == 7` and `n % 12 == 11`, but only 30-50% smaller subset of reminders modulus 60. My function `SieveOfAtkin_Arty_Numba()` (and Wiki too) shows which reminders to use.
4. Instead of keeping array `is_prime[]` of bool values or `byte` values (in case of Numpy), it is enough to keep an array of bits. This will reduce memory usage exactly **8 times**. This not only boost computation by usage of CPU Cache, but also allows to compute many more primes if you have a limited memory. Two Numba versions do bit arithmetics in order to work with bit array.
5. Numba pre-compilation does most of optimization work. Because it converts code to [LLVM Intermediate Representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM#Intermediate_representation), which is a kind of Assembly code, which is similar in speed to optimized C/C++ code. Basically due to help of Numba code becomes as fast as if you have written it in pure C/C++ and not Python. But still it is Python code, but automatically optimized by Numba.

Put a look at function `SieveOfAtkin_Arty_Python()` - this function is basically what you want to look at to study my code. It is in pure Python (without Numba), but **13.9** times faster than your original code, and **3.58** times faster speed wise than best other [answer of @bergee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71490622/941531).

If you don't want heavy Numba in your projects then it is best to copy-paste code of SieveOfAtkin_Arty_Python() function, it is best one out of pure Python solutions.

Before running a code do one time only install of packages `python -m pip install numba numpy -U`. If you don't like Numba, remove Numba and Numpy packages import from my first line of code and also delete two functions `SieveOfEratosthenes_Arty_Numba()` and `SieveOfAtkin_Arty_Numbda()`.

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow21783160#main.py)

```py
import numba as nb, numpy as np, math, time

def SieveOfAtkin_Arty_Python(limit):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin
    end = limit + 1
    sqrt_end = int(end ** 0.5 + 2.01)
    primes = [2, 3]
    is_prime = [False] * end
    for x in range(1, int((end / 4) ** 0.5 + 2.01)):
        xx4 = 4 * x * x
        for y in range(1, sqrt_end, 2):
            n = xx4 + y * y
            if n >= end:
                break
            if n % 12 == 1 or n % 12 == 5:
                is_prime[n] = not is_prime[n]
    for x in range(1, int((end / 3) ** 0.5 + 2.01), 2):
        xx3 = 3 * x * x
        for y in range(2, sqrt_end, 2):
            n = xx3 + y * y
            if n >= end:
                break
            if n % 12 == 7:
                is_prime[n] = not is_prime[n]
    for x in range(2, int((end / 2) ** 0.5 + 2.01)):
        xx3 = 3 * x * x
        for y in range(x - 1, 0, -2):
            n = xx3 - y * y
            if n >= end:
                break
            if n % 12 == 11:
                is_prime[n] = not is_prime[n]
    for x in range(5, sqrt_end):
        if is_prime[x]:
            for y in range(x * x, end, x * x):
                is_prime[y] = False
    for p in range(5, end, 2):
        if is_prime[p]:
            primes.append(p)
    return primes

def SieveOfEratosthenes_Arty_Python(limit):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
    end = limit + 1
    composite = [False] * end
    for i in range(3, int(end ** 0.5 + 2.01)):
        if not composite[i]:
            for j in range(i * i, end, i):
                composite[j] = True
    return [2] + [i for i in range(3, end, 2) if not composite[i]]

@nb.njit(cache = True)
def SieveOfEratosthenes_Arty_Numba(limit):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
    end = limit + 1
    composite = np.zeros(((end + 7) // 8,), dtype = np.uint8)
    for i in range(3, int(end ** 0.5 + 2.01)):
        if not (composite[i // 8] & (1 << (i % 8))):
            for j in range(i * i, end, i):
                composite[j // 8] |= 1 << (j % 8)
    return np.array([2] + [i for i in range(3, end, 2)
        if not (composite[i // 8] & (1 << (i % 8)))], dtype = np.uint32)

@nb.njit(cache = True)
def SieveOfAtkin_Arty_Numba(limit):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin
    # https://github.com/mccricardo/sieve_of_atkin/blob/master/sieve_of_atkin.py
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783160/
    end = limit + 1
    is_prime = np.zeros(((end + 7) // 8,), dtype = np.uint8)
    # Subset of n % 12 == 1 or n % 12 == 5
    set0 = np.array([int(i in {1, 13, 17, 29, 37, 41, 49, 53}) for i in range(60)], dtype = np.uint8)
    # Subset of n % 12 == 7
    set1 = np.array([int(i in {7, 19, 31, 43}) for i in range(60)], dtype = np.uint8)
    # Subset of n % 12 == 11
    set2 = np.array([int(i in {11, 23, 47, 59}) for i in range(60)], dtype = np.uint8)
    sqrt_end = int(math.sqrt(end) + 1.01)
    
    for x in range(1, int(sqrt_end / math.sqrt(4) + 2.01)):
        xx4 = 4 * x * x
        for y in range(1, sqrt_end, 2):
            n = xx4 + y * y
            if n >= end:
                break
            if set0[n % 60]:
                is_prime[n // 8] ^= 1 << (n % 8)
    for x in range(1, int(sqrt_end / math.sqrt(3) + 2.01), 2):
        xx3 = 3 * x * x
        for y in range(2, sqrt_end, 2):
            n = xx3 + y * y
            if n >= end:
                break
            if set1[n % 60]:
                is_prime[n // 8] ^= 1 << (n % 8)
    for x in range(2, int(sqrt_end / math.sqrt(2) + 2.01)):
        xx3 = 3 * x * x
        for y in range(x - 1, 0, -2):
            n = xx3 - y * y
            if n >= end:
                break
            if set2[n % 60]:
                is_prime[n // 8] ^= 1 << (n % 8)
    
    for n in range(7, sqrt_end):
        if is_prime[n // 8] & (1 << (n % 8)):
            for k in range(n * n, end, n * n):
                is_prime[k // 8] &= ~np.uint8(1 << (k % 8))
    
    return np.array([2, 3, 5] + [n for n in range(7, end, 2)
        if is_prime[n // 8] & (1 << (n % 8))], dtype = np.uint32)
        
def SieveOfAtkin_Mahadeva(limit):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/q/21783160/941531
    
    is_prime = [False] * (limit + 1)
    
    for x in range(1,int(math.sqrt(limit))+1):
        for y in range(1,int(math.sqrt(limit))+1):
            n = 4*x**2 + y**2

            if n<=limit and (n%12==1 or n%12==5):
                # print "1st if"
                is_prime[n] = not is_prime[n]
            n = 3*x**2+y**2
            if n<= limit and n%12==7:
                # print "Second if"
                is_prime[n] = not is_prime[n]
            n = 3*x**2 - y**2
            if x>y and n<=limit and n%12==11:
                # print "third if"
                is_prime[n] = not is_prime[n]

    for n in range(5,int(math.sqrt(limit))):
        if is_prime[n]:
            for k in range(n**2,limit+1,n**2):
                is_prime[k] = False
    return [2,3] + [n for n in range(5,limit) if is_prime[n]]

def SieveOfAtkin_bergee(limit):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/71490622/941531
    P = [2,3]
    r = range(1,int(math.sqrt(limit))+1)
    sieve=[False]*(limit+1)
    for x in r:
        for y in r:
            xx=x*x
            yy=y*y
            xx3 = 3*xx
            n = 4*xx + yy
            if n<=limit and (n%12==1 or n%12==5) : sieve[n] = not sieve[n]
            n = xx3 + yy
            if n<=limit and n%12==7 : sieve[n] = not sieve[n]
            n = xx3 - yy
            if x>y and n<=limit and n%12==11 : sieve[n] = not sieve[n]
    for x in range(5,int(math.sqrt(limit))):
        if sieve[x]:
            xx=x*x
            for y in range(xx,limit+1,xx):
                sieve[y] = False
    for p in range(5,limit):
        if sieve[p] : P.append(p)
    return P

def Test():
    limit = 5 * 10 ** 6
    # Do pretty printing of limit
    print(f'Limit', ''.join(reversed(''.join([['', '_'][i > 0 and i % 3 == 0] + c for i, c in enumerate(reversed(str(limit)))]))))
    rtim, rres = None, None
    for f in [
        SieveOfAtkin_Mahadeva,
        SieveOfAtkin_bergee, 
        SieveOfEratosthenes_Arty_Python,
        SieveOfAtkin_Arty_Python,
        SieveOfEratosthenes_Arty_Numba,
        SieveOfAtkin_Arty_Numba,
    ]:
        fname = f.__name__
        print(f'{fname:<31} : ', end = '', flush = True)
        f(1 << 10) # Pre-compute function, Numba needs it for pre-compilation
        tim = time.time()
        res = np.array(f(limit), dtype = np.uint32)
        tim = time.time() - tim
        if rtim is None:
            rtim = tim
        if rres is None:
            rres = res
        else:
            assert np.all(rres == res)
        print(f'time {tim:>7.3f} sec, boost {rtim / tim:>7.2f}x', flush = True)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test()
```