# python check prime, stuck at one point

Tags: python, computer-science, primes

This was the question our teacher gave us:

"One way to determine whether or not a number is a prime number is as follows:

if the number < 2, then return False

if the number is 2, then return True

for each value of i, where i >=2 and i < number:

if i divides the number evenly, then return False

return True"

I've managed to work through most of it, but was stuck when it said 'for each value of i, where i >=2 and i < number:'
how do I write this in code?

```
if number < 2:    
    return False
if number == 2:
    return True
?????????
    if i%2 == 0:
        return False
return True
```

Comment: See the links it will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833759/python-prime-number-checker  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114167/checking-if-a-number-is-a-prime-number-in-python

Comment: Has your teacher taught your recursion or looping constructs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo need a loop to check all numbers from 2 to one less than the number being checked. There are better ways to do it (such as only checking up to the square root of the number) but a simplistic algorithm would be:

```
def isPrime (n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    for x in range (2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

So, in terms of what you need to add to your code:

- a loop iterating some variable from two up to one less than the number.
- checking modulo with *that variable* rather than the hard-coded `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to start a loop from 2 to the number

```
for i in range(2,number)
    if number%i == 0:
          return false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isprime(num):
 #this is the part you are missing
 for divider in range(2,num):
   if num%divider == 0:
     return False
     #end of missing part

 return not num%2 == 0 or num==2 or num==0



for i in range(0,200):
    if isprime(i): print i, isprime(i)
```