# Finding a pair of prime numbers with a given arithmetic average using Python

Tags: python, average, primes

I must create a function `f(n)`, which will return a pair of prime numbers with arithmetic average `n`. For example f(10) = [3, 17], f(3) = [3, 3].

So far I have a problem working at the same time with two prime numbers:

```
def f(n):
    for i in range(2,a):
        for k in range(2,b):
            if a%i!=0 and b%k!=0:
                n=(a+b)/2
                return [a,b]
f(n)
```

Comment: You have to make it more clear.... Do you want to find a pair of prime numbers that have as average `n`, where `n` is input?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's create a function to check if a number is prime (a rather slow one):

```
def is_prime(n):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Then we notice that for two numbers to have average `n`, they must have sum `2 * n`. Also one of the numbers, let's say `x` will be lower or equal to `n`. So now it's straightforward:

```
def f(n):
    for x in range(2, n + 1): # Since smaller will be at most n
        y = 2 * n - x # Since x + y must be 2 * n
        if is_prime(x) and is_prime(y):
            return [x, y]
```

We can now test:

```
>>> f(10)
[3, 17]
>>> f(12)
[5, 19]
>>> f(3)
[3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the program only needs to find a pair of prime numbers, so surely you multiply the average (n) by 2, then find all pairs of integers which sum to it, then check if both are primes.

A brute force solution for checking for primes in python is:

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n==1 or n==0:
        return False
    for i in range(3,n):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True
```

Other faster solutions and this one can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833759/python-prime-number-checker).

Finding pairs of integers that sum to the average times 2 can be done through brute force (this returns each pair twice however):

```
def sums(n):
    return [[x,n-x] for x in range(1,n)]
```

Putting it all together, using these two functions:

```
def f(n):
    for a in sums(n*2):
        if is_prime(a[0]) and is_prime(a[1]):
            return a
    return 'None found'
```

Hope this is helpful.