# code that check if number is prime number

Tags: python, primes

I have code that checks if the number is prime or note

when I run it gives me an error

my code:

```
a = int (input("your numbre :"))
b = range(1,a+1)
if a%b == 0:
    for i in b :
        if b == a or b == 1:
            print("the numbre you input is prim number")
else:
    print("the nmubre you input is note prem numbre")
```

the error generated :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\chap8ex2.py", line 3, in <module>
    if a%b == 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'range'
```

Comment: the error is telling you exactly what's wrong, you can't mod and int by a range

Comment: i cant fix it can u help my

Comment: just show my the right way

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114167/checking-if-a-number-is-a-prime-number-in-python

Comment: Also, if this happens to be for a certain Project Euler: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n (because checking primes one by one=not the right way for project euler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range function creates an array of numbers between its parameters.
For example:

```
>>> range(1, 4)
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

In your code you're saying `a%b` which is finding the remainder between a number the user inputted and a range object. Think of the range object as a python list. So what you're doing is 5 % [1, 2, 3] that doesn't make sense. Check this separate thread to find out how to implement a prime number checker in python. [Python Prime number checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833759/python-prime-number-checker)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int (input("your numbre :"))
b = range(1,a+1)
for i in b :
    if b == a or b == 1:
        if a%b!=0:
            print("the number you input is prim number")
else:
    print("the number you input is not a prime number")
```