# prime numbers in python using for loop and break

Tags: python, primes

I have written a python code to find prime numbers between 2 and 30. But my code is not evaluating for 2 and 3. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code?

```
for i in range(2, 30):
    for j in range(2, i-1):
        if ((i % j) == 0):
            print(i, "is not a prime number")
            break
        else:
            print(i, "is a prime number")
        break
```

Comment: if i is 2 or 3, you won't enter the next for loop

Answer (score 2):

The logic of your code is wrong.  The `else` clause should be attached to the inner for loop, so it's only executed if the loop is exhausted without finding a divisor.

```
for i in range(2, 30):
    for j in range(2, i-1):
        if ((i % j) == 0):
            print(i, "is not a prime number")
            break
    else:
        print(i, "is a prime number")
```

Also note that the outer loop only runs up to 29, since the upper boundary is not included in a range.  The inner loop does not include `i - 1`, but that's totatlly fine, since any non-trivial divisor is less than `i - 1`.

The inner loop won't be entered at all for 2 and 3, since the range will be empty in these cases.  This is fine as well, since the else clause will be immediately entered.

Comment: Ok. Got it! I thought else can only be attached to if statement. Thanks.

Comment: @Laxman See https://stackoverflow.com/q/9979970/279627 for further information on `else` clauses on `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(2, 30):
    prime = True
    for j in range(2, i-1):
        if ((i % j) == 0):
            prime = False
            # print(i, "is not a prime number")
            break
        # else:
        #  print(i, "is a prime number")
        # break
    if prime:
        print(i, "is a prime number")
    else :
        print(i, "is not a prime number")
```

There are lot of online link to solve the prime number problem. To improve yourself search yourself and understand the. Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833759/python-prime-number-checker) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114167/checking-if-a-number-is-a-prime-number-in-python) link help you a lot. Happy codding

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because the nested `for` declaration:

```
for i in range(2, 30):
    for j in range(2, i-1):
```

Uses `range(2, i-1)` and until `i` is `4`, `range` returns no value:

```
i = 2 --> range(2, 1) # No value
i = 3 --> range(2, 2) # No value
i = 4 --> range(2, 3) # 2
```

This is because the `range` function returns values from the `first parameter` (included) to the `second parameter` (not included).