# Printing the number with the highest prime number of occurences

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the number with the highest number of prime occurrences. but it is printing the number an the times is printed.

```
#checking for the highest number 
import collections
a= [11,11,11,23,37,53,37,37,2,11,23,21,17,12,17,17,17,17,19,19,11,11,33,33]
counter=collections.Counter(a)
print counter.most_common(1)


#checking the number that occurs prime times


for n in a:
    times=a.count(n)
    root=times**0.5
    i=2

    while i<= root:
       if times% i != 0:
           print n
       i+=1
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you need? Can you provide any expected output and current output?

Comment: @magicleon the input is a and the output is 17 17 17 17 17         please run the project and see the output for better idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
a = [11,11,11,23,37,53,37,37,2,11,23,21,17,12,17,17,17,17,19,19,11,11,33,33]

def is_prime(n):
    from math import sqrt
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2:
        return False
    return all(n % i for i in range(3, int(sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))

counter = {k: a.count(k) for k in set(a)}

from operator import itemgetter
while True:
    maximum = max(counter.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
    if is_prime(maximum[1]):
        break
    else:
        counter.pop(maximum[0])
print(maximum)     # (17, 5)
print(maximum[0])  # 17
```

> `is_prime` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18833870/6162307)

In this case, `11` with 6 appearances is the most common but `6` is not a prime, so it gets disregarded. The second most common is `17` with `5` appearances. Since `5` is a prime, `17` is the answer.

Note that the check on whether the `count` is prime is performed on the element with the max count only to minimize the checks. If it is not, the element gets `pop`ed and the next one follows.

---

> For a solution without modules you can substitute the following part of the code in:

```
while True:
    maximum = max(counter.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
    if is_prime(maximum[1]):
        break
    else:
        counter.pop(maximum[0])
```

Comment: Well it is a great idea, but could you help me out with my logic, I was hoping not to use the modules. Could you see the issue please?

Comment: @HardipinderSingh A no-modules approach was also added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comprehension list to make it all easier to read

```
primes = [x for x in set(your_list) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range (2, x))]
max = 0
nr = -1
for x in primes:
    if primes.count(x) > max:
        max = primes.count(x)
        nr = x
```