# conditional not appending all correct integers to proper list

Tags: python

I can't seem to figure out a way to include some multiples into my non prime list. for examples "15" "49" "9" is considered a prime number. Any ideas or corrections ?

```
number = int(input("Enter a number. "))
non_prime = []
prime = []


def isPrime(number):
    for i in range(2,number):
        if number % i == 0:  
            return False
        else:
           return True

def append(number):
    for i in range(1,number+1):
        if isPrime(i) == True:
            prime.append(i)
        else:
            non_prime.append(i)


append(number)
print(non_prime)
print(prime)
print (len(prime))
```

Comment: Your `isPrime()` function needs to be revised. It's only separating odd numbers from even numbers

Comment: It's pretty easy to find algorithms to find primes if you search. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833759/python-prime-number-checker#18833870

Comment: Your `isPrime()` function is returning `True` too soon. You need to investigate more numbers, and once no divisor has been found, you exit the loop and `return True`.

Comment: Also, you don't need to investigate all possible divisors between `2` and `number`. Looping until the square root of `number` is sufficient... if a divisor hasn't been found then, then it will not be found anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if number % i == 0:  
   return False
else:
   return True
```

Your function returns true for all odd numbers, since it checks if they can be divided by 2 in the 'if' clause, and since they cannot be divided by 2, `isPrime` returns `True`. You can do the following:

```
def isPrime(number):
    for i in range(2,number):
        if number % i == 0:  
            return False
    return True
```

If a number can exit the for loop, it cannot be divided by any number up to it, so it is a prime number.

Comment: Almost correct. Your function would fail in the case of 1, however. 1 isn't prime

Comment: Absolutely true. My mistake.

Comment: There's another optimization: only loop till `math.sqrt(number)` instead of `number`. If a divisor hasn't been found then, it will not be found in the second part as well.

Comment: You could in fact return a one-liner: `return number > 1 and all(number % i for i in range(2, int(number ** 0.5) + 1))`