# prime factors for large numbers

Tags: python, prime-factoring

I wrote this to determine the largest prime factor of any given number. It works well for numbers with less than 9 digits but behaves in an indefinite manner when the number of digits goes beyond nine. How can I optimize it?

## This function determines if a number is a prime number

```
def is_prime(x):
    u = 1
    i = 2
    while i < x:
        if x%i == 0:
            u = 0
            break
        else:
            i = i+1
    return u
```

## This function determines if a number is a prime factor of another

```
def detprime(x,y):
    if x%y == 0:
        if (is_prime(y)):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        return 0
```

## This section checks for all the prime factors of a given number, stores them in a list, and returns the largest value

```
def functionFinal(x):
    import math
    factors = []
    y = x//2
    for i in range(1,y):
        if detprime(x,i) == 1:
            factors.append(i)
    y = len(factors)
    print(factors[y-1])

import time
start_time = time.process_time()
print("Enter a number")
num = int(input())
functionFinal(num)
```

print(time.process_time()-start_time)

Comment: Check up to the square root of `x` only.

Comment: You could fasten your prime number checker with function explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18833870/7918714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve your code by having a more efficient function to check primality. Apart form that, you need to only store the last element of your list `factors`. Also, you can increase the speed by JIT compiling the function and using parallelisation. In the code below, I use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org).

```
import math
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(cache=True)
def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2: 
        return 0
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return 0
    return 1

@nb.njit(cache=True)
def detprime(x, y):
    if x % y == 0:
        if (is_prime(y)):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        return 0

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def functionFinal(x):
    factors = [1]
    y = x // 2
    for i in nb.prange(1, y): # check in parallel
        if detprime(x, i) == 1:
            factors[-1] = i

    return factors[-1]
```

So, that

```
functionFinal(234675684)
```

has the performance comparison,

> > Your code : 21.490s
> >
> > Numba version (without parallel) : 0.919s
> >
> > Numba version (with parallel) : 0.580s

HTH.

Comment: Wow! What an improvement. Thanks.