# Shell script prime text

Tags: python, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to "traduce" from Python ([What is the best algorithm for checking if a number is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-checking-if-a-number-is-prime)) to Shell Script. This is my idea (probably very silly code):

```
#!/bin/bash
prime (){
i=5
w=2
while [ `echo "$i*$i" | bc -l ` -le $n ]
    do
      if [ n % i -eq 0 ]
        then echo "$n is not prime"
      else
        i = i + w
        w = 6 - w
        echo "$n is prime"
    fi
done
}
echo "Test for knowing if a number is prime or not."
sleep 2
echo "Enter the number"
read n
if [ $n -eq 1 ]
   then echo "Number 1 is not prime"
elif [ $n -eq 2 ]
   then echo "Number two is prime"
elif [ $n -eq 3 ]
   then echo "Number three is prime"
else
   prime
fi
```

The problem is when i put any other number (4, 5, 6, ...) the program doesn't return back if $n is prime or not. If anyone can help me, I will be very grateful.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I forgot that, so sorry. I edited the question. Thank's for the observation.

Comment: You've got a long night ahead of you if you want to keep going in the same vein...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were so many problems in the code. 
The main problem was that you did not implement the code given in that link properly. 
You did not check the divisibility by 2,3 (3rd and 4th conditions) so the code will just exit for numbers less that 25, so I added those conditions.
Further there were errors in the if statement, assignments etc.,
Please tell if you want any further clarifications.

Here is the corrected code

```
#!/bin/bash
prime (){
i=5
w=2
isprime=1
while [ `echo "$i*$i" | bc -l ` -le $n ]
    do
      if [ $((n % i)) -eq 0 ]
        then
        isprime=0
        break
      else
        i=$(($i+$w))
        w=$((6-$w))
    fi
done
if [ $isprime -eq 0 ]
  then echo "$n is not a prime"
else
  echo "$n is a prime"
fi
return 0
}
echo "Test for knowing if a number is prime or not."
echo "Enter the number"
read n
if [ $n -eq 1 ]
   then echo "Number 1 is not prime"
elif [ $n -eq 2 ]
   then echo "Number two is prime"
elif [ $n -eq 3 ]
   then echo "Number three is prime"
elif [ $((n % 2)) -eq 0 ]
   then echo "$n is not a prime"
elif [ $((n % 3)) -eq 0 ]
   then echo "$n is not a prime"
else
   prime
fi
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, my "transcription code" was too wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to `factor` from GNU core utilities:

```
f=$(factor 11 | wc -w); [[ $f -eq 2 ]] && echo prime || echo not prime
```

Output:

```
prime
```

---

```
f=$(factor 6 | wc -w); [[ $f -eq 2 ]] && echo prime || echo not prime
```

Output:

```
not prime
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't understand. What is factor?

Comment: `factor` is part of GNU core utilities and made for factorization/factoring. See: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/factor-invocation.html#factor-invocation