# How can I deal with this error in my Batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I'm not sure what is happening as batch script closes almost immediately when I try to run it. It's pretty simple it should test whether a number(`num`) is a prime Number. If not it continues until `num1` is bigger than `num`.

```
echo off
title Prime Numbers
cls
set /a prime=7
set /a num1=2
set /a num2=2
:do1
if %prime% == %num1% * %num2% goto do_if_1
if else %prime% LSS %num1% * %num2% set /a num2=%num2%+1
if else %prime% GTR %num1% * %num2% goto do_if_2
if else %prime% LSS %num1% * 1 goto do_if_3
goto do1
:do_if_1
set /a prime=%prime%+1
set /a num1=2
set /a num2=2
goto do1
:do_if_2
set /a num1=%num1%+1
set /a num2=2
goto do2
:do_if_3
echo %prime%
goto do_if_1
```

Comment: You can't do math within an IF statement.  You can only do arithmetic operations with SET /A.  And that is not the correct syntax for an IF ELSE statement.  Read the help for the SET and IF commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit: 6n±1 method

In case it's useful to anyone, here's a much more efficient method for testing whether a number is prime or composite.  It's a Batch language adaptation of the *6n±1* algorithm mentioned by [several people on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1801391/1683264).

```js
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1"=="" goto usage
for /f "delims=0123456789" %%I in ("%~1") do goto usage

if %~1 LEQ 1 (
    echo %~1 is neither prime nor composite.
    exit /b 1
) else if %~1 LEQ 3 (
    echo %~1 is prime.
    exit /b 0
)

set /a "mod2or3 = ^!(%~1 %% 2) | ^!(%~1 %% 3), half = %~1 / 2"
if %mod2or3% EQU 1 (
    echo %~1 is composite.
    exit /b 1
)

for /L %%I in (5,6,%half%) do (
    set /a "n6pm1 = ^!(%~1 %% %%I) | ^!(%~1 %% (%%I + 2))"
    if !n6pm1! EQU 1 (
        echo %~1 is composite.
        exit /b 1
    )
)

echo %~1 is prime.
goto :EOF

:usage
echo Usage: %~nx0 integer
goto :EOF
```

---

#### Original answer:

Thought I might accept the challenge.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1"=="" goto usage
for /f "delims=0123456789" %%I in ("%~1") do goto usage

set /a limit = %~1 - 1

for /L %%I in (2,1,%limit%) do (
    set /a modulo = %~1 %% %%I
    if !modulo! equ 0 (
        echo %~1 is composite ^(divisible by %%I^).
        goto :EOF
    )
)

echo %~1 is prime.
goto :EOF

:usage
echo Usage: %~nx0 integer
```

---

You had commented under Dominique's answer, "So how do I fix this?"  Take the first part of your script:

```js
set /a prime=7
set /a num1=2
set /a num2=2
:do1
if %prime% == %num1% * %num2% goto do_if_1
```

Since you've been informed by both Squashman and myself that `if %prime% == %num1% * %num2%` is not going to work as you intend, you should now know that you need to insert an additional `set /a` above your `if` statement to perform `%num1% * %num2%`.

```js
set /a prime=7
set /a num1=2
set /a num2=2
:do1
set /a product = num1 * num2
if %prime% == %product% goto do_if_1
```

Let's continue...

```js
...
if %prime% == %product% goto do_if_1
if else %prime% LSS %num1% * %num2% set /a num2=%num2%+1
```

There are two immediate problems here.  #1, I think you probably meant `else if`, not `if else`.  #2, in batch scripting, `else` needs to be included as a part of the `if` command you're `else`-ing.  This means `else` either needs to be appended to the end of the previous line, or you should use some parentheses.  Rewrite it like this:

```js
if %prime% == %product% (
    goto do_it_1
) else if %prime% LSS %product% (
    set /a num2 += 1
) else etc...
```

Comment: and that was how my batch script was shamed XD

Comment: sorry when i asked him i didn't even notice your edit sorry, but thxs it was useful

Comment: im getting to it i just noticed a problem in both our programs it has prime numbers and some non-prime

Comment: Mine agrees with https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/1000.txt up to 509.  I haven't checked beyond that, but I don't doubt it's correct for larger numbers.  Only problem with mine is that it's inefficient for big numbers.  I tried checking 2147483647 but I got bored and Ctrl-C'd it after 10 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I advise you, is to get rid of the `echo off`, like this you can follow what your script is doing:

```
D:\>set /a prime=7
D:\>set /a num1=2
D:\>set /a num2=2
D:\>if 7 == 2 * 2 goto do_if_1
7 was unexpected at this time. => this is causing your problem!
D:\>if else 7 LSS 2 * 2 set /a num2=2+1
D:\>
```

Comment: how was 7 unexpected?

Comment: It was certainly a surprise to me.  I think Dominique's major point was that the first step in troubleshooting a script that's throwing errors is to leave `echo` enabled, so you can see which part of the script is causing grief.  In this case, `if 7 == 2 * 2` isn't throwing the error, but it doesn't do what you think it does.  The error is being thrown when the script encounters `if else 7`.  It's treating `else` as a string literal, not a keyword.  It's treating `7` as a comparison operator, and complaining that `7` is neither `==` nor `equ` nor `gtr` nor any other operator it understands.

Comment: so how can i fix this? and even when i turn echo off it closes way too fast for me to actually read what it is saying.

Comment: @TheGamerLord See my edited answer.  Also, you should open a cmd prompt and execute your script by typing its name, rather than double-clicking on it.  That way the console window will stay open after execution completes.

Comment: @TheGamerLord, did you bother to read my comments under your original question.