# How do i implement these algorithms below

Tags: python, algorithm

**Alogrithm 1:**

> Get a list of numbers L1, L2, L3....LN as argument
>   Assume L1 is the largest, Largest = L1
>   Take next number Li from the list and do the following
>   If Largest is less than Li
>   Largest = Li
>   If Li is last number from the list then
>   return Largest and come out
>   Else repeat same process starting from step 3

**Algorithm 2:**

> Create a function prime_number that does the following
>   Takes as parameter an integer and
>   Returns boolean value true if the value is prime or
>   Returns boolean value false if the value is not prime

So far my code is :

```
def get_algorithm_result(num_list):    
    largest =num_list[0]        
    for item in range(0,len(num_list)):    
        if largest < num_list[item]:                
            largest = num_list[item]    
    return largest

def prime_number(integer):    
    if integer%2==0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

After executing the code i get

```
"Test Spec Failed

Your solution failed to pass all the tests"
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: your prime_number function just checks for divisibility by 2???

Comment: what     prime_number     do in another function?

Comment: Obviously your `prime_number` function does not really check for prime numbers, just for odd numbers.

Comment: I can't quite understand what you are trying to achieve with those methods. Please elaborate it.

Comment: suppose i change prime_number function by adding :statement ...............if integer%2==0 and 2!=integer:   would it work

Comment: If an integer is odd, and not 2, is it prime? No.

Comment: No...it will not. Prime number is not divisible by **any** number other than 1 and itself. The most naive way would be to check divisibility by all numbers in range `2..(n-1)`

Comment: works fine after adding.Thanks

Comment: @phil a prime is divisible by just 1 and itself..so maybe see the given integer is divisible by other numbers? If so return False....btw you don't really need to check the divisibility with all the other integers till the given integer..but I will let you figure that one out

Comment: Read [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-checking-if-a-number-is-prime) and the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) on primality testing.

Comment: @astrosyam i finally figured it out.@ Reti43 thanks for the info also :

Comment: def prime_number(integer):
    if integer>=1:
        for i in range(2,integer):
            if (integer % i) == 0:
                return False
                break
        else:
            return True

Answer (score 0):

Is what you mean with the first one find the largest number? Then you should use max() like

```
list = [1,2,4,5,3]
print max(list)
>>> 5
```

This should help with the second one:

```
def prime_number(n):

    if n > 1:
       for x in range(2,n):
           if (n % x) == 0:
               return False
               break
       else:
           return True
```

If a number is prime, then the factors are only 1 and itself. If there is any other factor from 2 to the number, it is not prime. n % x finds the remainder when n is divided by x. If x is a factor of n, then n % x has a remainder of 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_algorithm_result(numbers):
  largest = numbers[0]
  for i in numbers:
    if largest < i:
      largest = i
return largest
```

and

```
def prime_number(number):
  if number > 1:
    for i in range(2, number):
      if (number % i) == 0:
        return False
      else:
        return True
  else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_algorithm_result(numb):
  largest = numb[0]
  for Li in numb:
    if largest < Li:
      largest = Li
    if Li == numb[-1]:
      return largest
    else:
      continue

def prime_number(primes):
  if primes > 1:
    for i in range(3, primes):
      if (primes % i) == 0:
        return False
      else:
        return True
  else:
    return False
```