# if conditional when finding prime number - always returning false

Tags: javascript

```
var enteredValue = prompt("enter a number");
enteredValue = enteredValue + 0;
console.log(isPrime(enteredValue));

function isPrime(num) {
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? The code is always returning false.

Comment: `return` ends your loop - and your function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the return of `true` out side of the loop, because you need to check all factors before returning `true`.

```js
var enteredValue = +prompt("enter a number");
console.log(isPrime(enteredValue));

function isPrime(num) {
    for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should return true outside of your for loop. With your example you are retuening in first iteratin, by entering else block.

This will work:

```
function isPrime(num) {
   for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
     if (num % i === 0) {
       return false; // return if  it's not a prime
     }
   }
   return true; // return only if it's a prime number
}
```

You can also check other prime solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200089/is-a-number-prime).