# Why it is going in an infinite loop despite being in different functions?

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to print all prime numbers between two given numbers (`num1`  and `num2`). If I am using a different variable name in the for loop of `isPrime` function, that works as expected. But while using same variable name as `i` it goes into an infinite loop. Why is this the case?

Below is my code:

```
showPrimeNumbers();

function showPrimeNumbers(){
    var num1 = 10;
    var num2 = 15;
    for (i=num1; i<=num2; i++){
        if(isPrime(i)){
            console.log(i+" is a prime number.");
        }
    }
}

function isPrime(num){
    var flag = true;
    for (i=2;i<=num-1;i++){
        if(num%i == 0){
            flag=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: You haven't declared `i` in either functions, it is global and both loops are messed up with its value.

Comment: because `i` is global. Declare it individually in each `for`. So, instead of `for (i` have `for ( var i`

Comment: btw your `isPrime` function can be made to be a slight bit faster https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200089/is-a-number-prime

Answer (score 2):

Your `i`s do not have `var` or `let` in front of them, so they're both referring to (and implicitly assigning to) the same global variable. So, every time `isPrime` runs, `i` gets reset to either 3 or 4, repeating - it'll never get to 15.

Never implicitly assign to global variables. Put `let` in front of the `i`s instead.

Something else that might make the code a bit clearer, instead of having a `flag` variable that might be reassigned, would be to simply `return false` or `return true`:

```js
showPrimeNumbers();

function showPrimeNumbers(){
    var num1 = 10;
    var num2 = 15;
    for (let i=num1; i<=num2; i++){
        if(isPrime(i)){
            console.log(i+" is a prime number.");
        }
    }
}

function isPrime(num){
    for (let i=2;i<=num-1;i++){
        if(num%i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using `var`. This means that JavaScript searches up and up the nested locals until it finds a variable `i`, and if it can't find one it creates a global variable. This means that the two functions share the variable `i`.

Fix it by writing `var i;` somewhere in each function.

In future, consider using strict mode by writing `"use strict"` at the beginning of each function body. It makes these sorts of errors much easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you declared the `i` variable without `var` keyword in your loops, so it will be a global variable in the `window` scope.

So both functions will be accessing the same `i` variable, and it will be updated by both functions in the same time, so `isPrime()` will reset the `i` variable to `2` and it won't be higher than `4`, so the exiting condition of your  first `for` loop won't be met because `i<=num2` will remain always `true`, that's why you got the infinite loop.

Just use `var` when you declare it inside each loop, so you will be dealing with two separate variables, where each one is local to a different function's scope.

```
for (var i=num1; i<=num2; i++)
```

And:

```
for (var i=2;i<=num-1;i++)
```