# How to optimize the project euler #10 problem for FCC environment?

Tags: javascript, optimization, primes

// the following code is generating accurate answer in my editor, but I want to optimize the code to pass the tests in freecodecamp environment. Can anybody shed the light upon this problem?

```
            function isPrime(param) {
                if (param == 2) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (param % 2 == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                var max = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(param));
                for (var i = 3; i <= max; i += 2) {
                    if (param % i == 0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }


            function primeSummation(n) {
                var primeArr = [];
                for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
                    if (isPrime(i)) {
                        primeArr.push(i);
                    }
                }
                var sumArray = primeArr.reduce(function add(a, b) {
                    return a + b;
                }, 0);
                console.log(sumArray)
                return sumArray;
            }

            primeSummation(2000000);
```

Comment: You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200089/javascript-number-prime-test) to find if number is prime or not & also normal `for` will be better than `reduce`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's great that you've joined bootcamp. There's a lot to learn, I keep my fingers crossed. If you're looking for best algorithm, that counts primes, this question has already been answered on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-checking-if-a-number-is-prime

Comment: I would give primeArr to the isPrime function, at the moment you check for prime against every single odd number <= sqrt(candidate) when you can check against the primes <= sqrt(candidate number) this should cut drastically on the number of tests sqrt(2e6)=1414 and there's only about 220 primes but 700 odd numbers that 3.5 times more ! Also in prime summation you can add 2 as a prime and skip even numbers the same way you did it in isPrime.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a long range of natural numbers (1...n) to check for them being prime, then it is not efficient to test them individually like you do with `isPrime`. It will be more efficient to perform the [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) over that range and then calculate the sum from the resulting array.