# Project Euler #27: Is there a more optimal way to solve this problem?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am doing the [Quadratic Primes](https://projecteuler.net/problem=27) question. My solution is pretty much just loop through every possible option and return the best.

I know that nested loops are not optimal and there's probably a smarter way to find the answer. But I can't think of one that isn't brute force. Here's my code:

```
var isPrime = function(num) {
    if (num <= 1) {
        return false;
    }
    // The check for the number 2 and 3
    if (num <= 3) {
        return true; 
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0 || num % 3 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 5; i * i <= num; i = i + 6) {
        if (num % i == 0 || num % (i + 2) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

var main = function () {
    var max = 0;
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;
    for (var i = -999; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (var j = -1000; j <= 1000; j++) {
            var n = 0;
            while(1) {
                var temp = Math.pow(n, 2) + (n * i) + j;
                if (isPrime(temp)) {
                    if (n > max) {
                        max = n;
                        a = i;
                        b = j;
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                n++;
            }
        }
    }
    return a * b;
}

console.log(main());
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have some generic comments: (1) I'm not sure how about your prime checking algorithms, but usually it's enough to check `i` until `sqrt(num)`. (2) You can use a hash table with all checked prime numbers to avoid re-checking the same numbers again; (3) `|a| < 1000` means `a` is from -999 to 999, and `|b| <= 1000` means `b` is from -1000 to 1000. Your loops are a bit wrong, they should be `i=-999; i < 1000` and `j=-1000; j <= 1000`.

Comment: Okay cool! thanks for the feedback.
1. I thought I was doing that with the loop ending that i * i <= num. But I can update it if you think it's faster.
2. Okay, great idea, that will speed it up a bit.
3. Okay, I'll update it now.
Thanks @ŁukaszNojek

Comment: To be honest, I am not aware of the prime check algorithm you wrote, so I'm not sure if the restriction in (1) will be correct. Have you invented it by yourself or found somewhere?

Comment: I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40200089/7918809

Comment: For the prime optimization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the algorithm runs very quickly even in JavaScript, there is some area for optimization.

Take a look at the formula: **x = n<sup>2</sup> + an + b**.

`n` will be *odd* (1, 3, 5, ...) and *even* (2, 4, 6, ...). Our goal is to make sure that `x` is always *odd*, because no even integer other than 2 is prime.

## Reminder of rules

odd * odd = odd (3 * 7 = 21)

odd * even = even (3 * 6 = 18)

even * even = even (4 * 8 = 32)

odd + odd = even (3 + 7 = 10)

odd + even = odd (3 + 6 = 9)

even + even = even (4 + 6 = 10)

## n<sup>2</sup>

If `n` is *odd*, `n` squared will be also *odd*: 1<sup>2</sup> = 1, 3<sup>2</sup> = 9, 5<sup>2</sup> = 25, ...

If `n` is *even*, `n` squared will be also *even*: 2<sup>2</sup> = 4, 4<sup>2</sup> = 8, 6<sup>2</sup> = 36, ...

So we have alternating *odd* and *even* values.

## a*n

If `a` is *odd*, then:

- for *odd* `n`, `a*n` is *odd*
- for *even* `n`, `a*n` is *even*
- so we again have alternating *odd* and *even* values.

If `a` is *even*, then `a*n` is always *even*.

## n<sup>2</sup> + a*n

So far, we have **n<sup>2</sup> + an**, which:

- for *odd* `a` is equal to *odd + odd = even* or *even + even = even*; so it's always *even*
- for *even* `a` is equal to *odd + even = odd* or *even + even = even*; so it's alternating *odd* and *even*

## b

There is just one coefficient left - `b`. It is a constant, which added to the previous value should yield *odd* values.

That means we have to ignore *even* `a`, because a constant added to alternating *odd* and *even* values will also give alternating values, so the formula `x` will fail after just a few steps.

Since `a` must be *odd*, **n + an** is *even*.

Therefore, to make `x` *odd*, we must take an *odd* `b`: *even + odd = odd*.

## Summary

We have to focus only on *odd* `a` and *odd* `b` values, which will limit the number of cases to check by roughly 4 (= 2 * 2).

Comment: if `a` and `n` both are even and `b` is odd, still `x` will be odd, `even + even + odd`, so why `a` must be odd?

Comment: Because you want to test for `n` from `1` upwards: `1, 2, 3, 4, ...`, so `n` will be once *odd* and the other time *even*. This will change the parity of `x` as `n` changes. And once you get `x` that is *even* and bigger than `2` - it won't be a prime. Therefore that for *even* `a` you will get low scores.