# How to find the previous prime number?

Tags: javascript

May be the question is so clear and doesn't need any more explanation but this is examples previous primes:

```
The previous prime of 19 is ===> 17
The previous prime of 211 is===> 199
```

My failing trial

```
const getPreviousPrime = (number) => {
    for(let i = number - 1; i >= 2; i--) {
       for(let j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++ ) {
          if(i % j === 0) break
          return i
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Show an example where your trial is wrong.  Then figure out what exactly your code does in that example, and you'll probably solve this question yourself.

Comment: my code just abstract 2 from the original number

Comment: What's with `j <= 9` ?  Shouldn't it be `j <= Math.sqrt(i)`.

Comment: Might be helpful to start with a prime number algorithm, and work your way back from there.

Comment: @James thanks james but still i have the same problem

Comment: This feels like homework, so I don't think we *should* give an exact right answer.  Nonetheless, I see a deleted answer pointing out that your return statement is in the wrong place; that's one of your problems.

Comment: @Brilliand it is not a homework, and i am struggling here for 1 hour trying to solve it, not all people starts good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by writing assuming you have an `isPrime()` function.

Then you can write the loop easily.

```
const getPreviousPrime = (number) => {
  for (let i = number - 1; i >= 2; i--) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}
```

You can find many implementations of `isPrime()` at [Number prime test in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200089/number-prime-test-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you, problems can be easier, just the way to start,

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help you.

```
const getPreviousPrime = (number) => {
    for(let i = number - 1; i >= 2; i--) {
        let prime = true;
        for(let j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++ ) {
            if(i % j === 0) {
                prime = false
                break;
            }
        }
        if (prime == true) {
            return i
        }
    }
    return 2;
}

console.log(getPreviousPrime(19))
console.log(getPreviousPrime(211))
```