# how to resolve sum of prime-indexed elements?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Good morning, am getting stuck with this kata, anyone can explain me ?
In this kata i have to return the sum of elements occupying prime-numbered indices.
I started my code like that, but didn't know what to do next. THANK YOU in advance.

```
function total(arr) {
  for (let i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) {}
};
```

Comment: At least try for some approach before asking.

Comment: i have been on for 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please use `;` after breaking condition which is `i < arr.length` here `for (let i = 2; i < arr.length, i++) {}`
2. You can loop over arr the way you are doing here and validate if index at which you are looping is prime itself.
3. If 2nd step is met you can add the value into summation var `sum`
4. return `sum`.

Please follow this thread to find know more about calculating if value is prime. [Number prime test in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200089/number-prime-test-in-javascript)

```
function isPrime(num) {
  for(var i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
  return num > 1;
}

function total(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (let i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(isPrime(i)) {
        sum = sum + arr[i]
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```