# Finding prime number in a range in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, primes

I'm trying to solve this problem where you loop through the numbers between 1 to 60 to find the total prime numbers. Here is what I've come up with:

```
var totalPrimeNumber = 0;
for(let i=1; i<=60; i++) {
    for(let j= 2; j< i; j++) {
        if(i%j ==0) {
            console.log(i, "is not a prime number");
        }
        console.log(i, "is a prime number");
        totalPrimeNumber+=1;
    }
}
```

But the output is wrong:

```
3 is a prime number
4 is not a prime number
4 is a prime number
4 is a prime number
5 is a prime number
5 is a prime number
5 is a prime number
6 is not a prime number
6 is a prime number
6 is not a prime number
6 is a prime number
6 is a prime number
6 is a prime number
7 is a prime number
7 is a prime number
7 is a prime number
```

Do you know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: You need to `break;` out of the loop once you've established that a number is not prime. Also for checking primes, `let j=2; j<=Math.sqrt(i); j++` is sufficient.

Comment: A better approach is to write a function `isPrime(number)` that returns a boolean and to call it in the loop for each value of `i`. Split your problems into smaller problems and handle them one at a time. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/nha613vg/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number prime test in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200089/number-prime-test-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You should **break the inner loop** once you know that the number is not a prime!

You can also improve your code by only checking numbers up to the square-root as divider. E.g. if you check 100 to be a prime, then you only need to check numbers up to 10 since higher numbers will have a lower multiplicator (e.g. you don't need to check 50 since you already checked 2 and 2*50 = 100)

```js
var totalPrimeNumber = 0;
for (let i = 1; i <= 60; i++) {
  let prime = i > 1;
  for (let j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) {
      prime = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (prime) {
    console.log(i, "is a prime number");
    totalPrimeNumber += 1;
  } else {
    console.log(i, "is not a prime number");
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that the SO console misses everything below 11 but they are there!

Answer (score 1):

You could also try Array.filter to select only those numbers in an Array that are primes, for example:

```js
function isPrime(n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    for(let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if(n % i === 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

const count = 60;
const numbers = Array.from({ length: count}, (v,k) => k + 1);
const primes = numbers.filter(n => isPrime(n))
console.log("Primes:", primes)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your interest is mainly in the result, and not implementation, then the optimum solution would be via [prime-lib](https://github.com/vitaly-t/prime-lib) library:

```
import {generatePrimes, stopOnValue} from 'prime-lib';

const i = generatePrimes(); // primes iterator

const arr = [...stopOnValue(i, 60)]; // produce primes up to 60

console.log(arr); //=> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, ..., 59]
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function primeFinder(n) {
  // Write your code here
  if(n === 2){
    return true;
  }
  if(n < 2 || isNaN(n) || (n%2===0)){
    return false;
  }
  for(let i = 3; i < n; i++){
    if(n%i === 0){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

for(let i = 0; i <= 11; i++){
  if(primeFinder(i) === true){
    console.log(i);
  }
}

console.log(`${primeFinder(11)}`)

// Leave this so we can test your code:
module.exports = primeFinder;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).